# Generating shuffled range using a PRNG rather than shuffling

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, random, shuffle

Is there any known algorithm that can generate a shuffled range [0..n) in linear time and constant space (when output produced iteratively), given an arbitrary seed value?

Assume n may be large, e.g. in the many millions, so a requirement to potentially produce every possible permutation is not required, not least because it's infeasible (the seed value space would need to be huge). This is also the reason for a requirement of constant space. (So, I'm specifically not looking for an array-shuffling algorithm, as that requires that the range is stored in an array of length n, and so would use linear space.)

I'm aware of [question 162606](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162606/iterating-shuffled-0-n-without-arrays), but it doesn't present an answer to this particular question - the mappings from permutation indexes to permutations given in that question would require a huge seed value space.

Ideally, it would act like a [LCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with a period and range of `n`, but the art of selecting `a` and `c` for an LCG is subtle. Simply satisfying the constraints for `a` and `c` in a full period LCG may satisfy my requirements, but I am wondering if there are any better ideas out there.

Comment: Do you want to output the whole range, or just a few elements of it?

Comment: How much of the range: I don't know at the start. That is configurable. It will probably be only a fraction of the full range, but it may be e.g. 10000 items out of a 10001 range, so e.g. just selecting random items and testing for duplicates wouldn't be good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on [Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464476/generating-shuffled-range-using-a-prng-rather-than-shuffling#465473), I've made a simple straightforward implementation in C#. Find the next largest power of two greater than N. This makes it trivial to generate a and c, since c needs to be relatively prime (meaning it can't be divisible by 2, aka odd), and (a-1) needs to be divisible by 2, and (a-1) needs to be divisible by 4. Statistically, it should take 1-2 congruences to generate the next number (since 2N >= M >= N).

```cs
class Program
{
    IEnumerable<int> GenerateSequence(int N)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int M = NextLargestPowerOfTwo(N);
        int c = r.Next(M / 2) * 2 + 1; // make c any odd number between 0 and M
        int a = r.Next(M / 4) * 4 + 1; // M = 2^m, so make (a-1) divisible by all prime factors, and 4

        int start = r.Next(M);
        int x = start;
        do
        {
            x = (a * x + c) % M;
            if (x < N)
                yield return x;
        } while (x != start);
    }

    int NextLargestPowerOfTwo(int n)
    {
        n |= (n >> 1);
        n |= (n >> 2);
        n |= (n >> 4);
        n |= (n >> 8);
        n |= (n >> 16);
        return (n + 1);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        foreach (int n in p.GenerateSequence(1000))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, I guess implementing LCG is probably the handiest solution - though I will keep looking at the questoin in case there are other ideas out there. One tip: the modulo M can be reduced to an and, so (...) & (M - 1) should be slightly more efficient.

Comment: Also, upon testing: you should probably consider using unsigned arithmetic, or 64-bit arithmetic, as the multiplication a*x will easily overflow for largeish N.

Comment: I think there might be a bug in this code. The `start` variable is set to a random number smaller than M, but instead should be set to the first value of x returned by `yield return x` in order for `while (x != start)` to behave as expected. Awesome code though!

Answer (score 7):

Here is a Python implementation of the [Linear Congruential Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) from [FryGuy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464476/generating-shuffled-range-using-a-prng-rather-than-shuffling/#467767). Because I needed to write it anyway and thought it might be useful for others.

```
import random
import math

def lcg(start, stop):
    N = stop - start

    # M is the next largest power of 2
    M = int(math.pow(2, math.ceil(math.log(N+1, 2))))

    # c is any odd number between 0 and M
    c = random.randint(0, M/2 - 1) * 2 + 1

    # M=2^m, so make (a-1) divisible by all prime factors and 4
    a = random.randint(0, M/4 - 1) * 4 + 1

    first = random.randint(0, M - 1)
    x = first
    while True:
        x = (a * x + c) % M
        if x < N:
            yield start + x
        if x == first:
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for x in lcg(100, 200):
        print x,
```

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you want an algorithm which is guaranteed to produce a cycle from 0 to n-1 without any repeats. There are almost certainly a whole bunch of these depending on your requirements; [group theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_theory) would be the most helpful branch of mathematics if you want to delve into the theory behind it.

If you want fast and don't care about predictability/security/statistical patterns, an LCG is probably the simplest approach. The wikipedia page you linked to contains this (fairly simple) set of requirements:

> The period of a general LCG is at most
>   m, and for some choices of a much less
>   than that. The LCG will have a full
>   period if and only if:
>
> 1. c and m are relatively prime,
> 2. a - 1 is divisible by all prime factors of m
> 3. a - 1 is a multiple of 4 if m is a multiple of 4

Alternatively, you could choose a period N >= n, where N is the smallest value that has convenient numerical properties, and just discard any values produced between n and N-1. For example, the lowest N = 2<sup>k</sup> - 1 >= n would let you use [linear feedback shift registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LFSR) (LFSR). Or find your favorite cryptographic algorithm (RSA, AES, DES, whatever) and given a particular key, figure out the space N of numbers it permutes, and for each step apply encryption once.

If n is small but you want the security to be high, that's probably the trickiest case, as any sequence S is likely to have a period N much higher than n, but is also nontrivial to derive a nonrepeating sequence of numbers with a shorter period than N. (e.g. if you could take the output of S mod n and guarantee nonrepeating sequence of numbers, that would give information about S that an attacker might use)

Answer (score 3):

See my article on [secure permutations with block ciphers](http://blog.notdot.net/2007/9/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-2-Secure-permutations-with-block-ciphers) for one way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Look into Linear Feedback Shift Registers, they can be used for exactly this.
The short way of explaining them is that you start with a seed and then iterate using the formula

```
x = (x << 1) | f(x)
```

where f(x) can only return 0 or 1.

If you choose a good function `f`, x will cycle through all values between 1 and 2^n-1 (where n is some number), in a good, pseudo-random way.
Example functions can be found [here](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp052.pdf), e.g. for 63 values you can use

```
f(x) = ((x >> 6) & 1) ^ ((x >> 5) & 1)
```