# Visiting every cell in a grid in pseudorandom order without temporary storage

Tags: algorithm

Suppose you have an NxN grid, and you want to visit every cell exactly once, and in a pseudorandom order. The order doesn't have to be very random, but it does have to be seedable so that a different permutation of the grid cell ordering is possible. Is there a way to do this without simply generating a list of all cell coordinates, randomly permuting it, and indexing out of it? I mean, I want a formula (or rather, a general way of constructing such a formula) that can transform indices `(i,j)` into `(i',j')` in a one-to-one, fully-covering way.

Followup (actually intended) question: Can the same be done for an NxN grid where we only want to visit those elements for which `i>j` (the lower triangle)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since each number N in the range 0..ROWS*COLS-1 deterministically points to a cell (N DIV ROWS, N MOD ROWS) this question is equivalent to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693880/create-random-number-sequence-with-no-repeats). It has some useful answers and references.

Comment: The Linear Feedback Shift Register looks like the best approach, though it looks like it requires you to pick an N that is a power of 2 (and then discard all values over your actual N).

Comment: Actually, I found that just doing f(x) = (x*p mod N) works fine to uniquely run through all 0..N, where p is a large prime number.

Comment: @VictorLiu I am doubtless misunderstanding, but when x=0, f(x)=0 forever. How can this cycle through 0..N?

Comment: @VictorLiu, and when I skip 0 and start with x=1, with N=6140 and p=982451653, I get a short cycle of 5 numbers. For a given N, can I choose a p which will visit ever number 0..N without producing shorter cycles?

Comment: @VictorLiu Ah, I see the answers to all my questions are at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator (which specifies (x * p + c) mod N, along with some conditions for choosing p and c.

Answer (score 2):

First, change the problem from a two dimensional one to a one dimensional one (any N dimensional array can be treated as a 1 dimensional array with the right algorithm for converting a one dimensional index into an N dimensional index).  You want an algorithm that will visit every value between 0 and N exactly once in a seedable pseudo-random fashion with either no, or O(1) storage requirements (its unclear from your question).  I personally know of no such algorithm, and doubt one exists, but then again I can't prove one doesn't exist so maybe someone cleverer than I am can provide.

**EDIT**

I'm wrong.  You can use a [Linear Feedback Shift Register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register).  The wikipedia page shows how to set up for a maximal LSFR's from 1 to 19 bits long, and has a link to a PDF which has the setup for registers up to 168 bits long.  It shouldn't be difficult to implement an algorithm which will give you pseudo-random value from 1 to any N

```
// a 31 bit LFSR
// based on http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5276320
public static int getNextValue(int register) {
    int t31 = (register & (1 << 30)) >>> 30; 
    int t28 = (register & (1 << 27)) >>> 27;
    int input = t31 ^ t28;
    register <<= 1;
    register |= input;
    register &= 0x7fffffff; // mask with this to ensure 0s in the high order bits
    return register;
}

public static int getNextValueBelowN(int value, int n) {
    do {
        value = getNextValue(value);
    } while (value > n);
    return value;
}
```

An obvious optimization for the latter function would be to analyze N and find LFSR function for the closest bit length to it, this minimizing misses in the while loop

**END EDIT**

On the second part, hitting only the lower triangle just means you need to reduce N and change the way you convert the one dimensional index into a two dimensional one.  For instance:

```
public static int getMaxValue(int dimension) {
    int retVal = 0;
    while (dimension > 0) {
        retVal += dimension--;
    }
    return retVal;
}


public static int getMaxValueFast(int dimension) {
    int retVal = 0;
    if (dimension % 1 == 1) {
        retVal += dimension--;
    }
    retVal += ((dimension + 1) * dimension / 2);
    return retVal;
}



public static Point getCoordinates(int index, int dimension) {
    Point retVal = new Point();
    while (index >= dimension) {
        ++retVal.x;
        index -= dimension--;
    }
    retVal.y = index;
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark cells as visited. For this you can just generate tuples at random and only visit a cell if you haven't already visited it.

For lower-triangular, you can also use a marking process to keep track of those that you've already visited, but now when you generate integers `i` and `j`, throw it away if `i` equals `j` and otherwise use the tuple `(i, j)` if `i > j` and `(j, i)` if `j > i`.

Comment: To mark a cell as visited, you'd need additional (temporary) storage.

Comment: Marking cells as visited pre-supposes storage for that purpose.  Additionally, if you're just using a random value for the index, then your runtime will become unreasonably long as the further into your method you get, the more frequently you'll encounter a cell which has been marked visited.  On the last cell you're basically throwing darts over and over hoping to hit the one remaining spot on the board which isn't taken.