# can we write that function in c form

Tags: c#, c, random

When I read some question to write random nuber generator ,I saw that function and it 
efficient but it is written in C#. I want see that function in form of c 
language,can anyone help?

```
IEnumerable<int> ForLargeQuantityAndRange(int quantity, int range)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < quantity; n++)
    {
        int r = Random(range);

        while (!used.Add(r))
            r = Random(range);

        yield return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not to mention that if the intent of the "while (!used.Add(r))" call is to prevent repeats, you could theoretically enter an infinite loop if quantity > range or if you're just unlikely and hit a cycle in the RNG. Either way, the later numbers will take longer to generate than the early ones. Short answer: that algorithm stinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions regarding number generators for C have been asked before here on SO, such as in the article "[Create Random Number Sequence with No Repeats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693880/create-random-number-sequence-with-no-repeats)".

I'd suggest looking at the above article to see if anything is suitable and provides a useful alternative to the standard rand() function in C, assuming that you've already looked at the latter and rejected it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite a function, as function in C or C++. This is a co-routine, which may be resumed.

To implement it in C, you will need to maintain external state, and provide a "next value" func.

The advantage of this function is that it guarantees unique values. Do you really need it? If not, use stdlib's rand, multiplied by proper factors.

Comment: I need,because I must use efficient random number generator

Comment: @gcc: You are aware that maintaining uniqueness actually makes this approach less efficient than just using `rand` when you don't actually need uniqueness, right?

Comment: well that generator is quite inefficient for the case when quantity is close to range. A shuffle would be much better in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want random numbers? If so, why don't you use one of the many libraries out there that can do it for you in a cross platform fashion? [Here](http://randomlib.sourceforge.net/)'s one.

Answer (score 0):

To write a co-routine in C, you need to maintain state.  This simplest way to do this is to use a `static` variable.  For this example, it would look something like:

```
int ForLargeQuantityAndRange(int init_quantity, int init_range)
{
    static int n;
    static int quantity, range;

    if (init_quantity > 0)
    {
        n = 0;
        quantity = init_quantity;
        range = init_range;
    }

    if (n++ < quantity)
    {
        int r = Random(range);

        while (!used_add(r))
            r = Random(range);

        return r;
    }

    /* Quantity exceeded */
    return -1;
}
```

...where you would call it with `(quantity, range)` to intialise a new sequence, and `(0, 0)` to continue the previous sequence.

Note that you will have to supply implementations of the `Random()` and `used_add()` functions.

Comment: There is no Random() function in any standard C library that I am aware of.  The ISO C standard specifies rand() and related functions, and BSD has random() [not Random()], which is supported I believe by the GNU C compiler for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @Joel Hoff: Yes, the user would have to implement both the `Random()` and `used_add()` functions - I was addressing only how to reimplement the co-routine structure in C.