# What is the most efficient way to generate unique pseudo-random numbers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create Random Number Sequence with No Repeats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693880/create-random-number-sequence-with-no-repeats)

I'm trying to generate unique session IDs. Each session ID is a random integer. The main requirement is that each session ID is unique. I'm trying to find the most efficient algorithm to do this.

Scenario: Generate 10  random numbers from 1 to 10 inclusive.

My algorithm:

```
// Generate unique pseudo-random numbers between 1 and 10 inclusive

vector<int> vList;

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    vList.push_back(i); 
}

// vList should have {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
{
    int k = (rand() % vList.size());
    cout << vList[k] << " ";
    vList.erase(vList.begin() + k);
}

// Sample output: 5 1 10 7 8 2 4 9 3 6
```

This algorithm has a time complexity of O(n) and a space complexity of O(n). Is there a more efficient algorithm?

Comment: use a GUID for session ID's...

Comment: Have a look at Fisher-Yates shuffling: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle

Comment: @Mitch: A GUID is not random.

Comment: @andora : a GUID is effectively unique. which is what is really required for a session ID

Comment: @Mitch: Ideally a session ID should not be 'just' unique, but unpredictable, else it can be predicted and possibly hijacked/compromised. GUIDs are designed for uniqueness and are potentially predictable and therfore not 'ideal' for session-IDs, but as always, it depends on the application/situation and therefore may be acceptable as session-IDs. A simple hashed GUID+salt may be better.

Comment: @andora: could you describe how a GUID is predictable please. Wouldn't that mean you have a significant amount of information about a client machine?

Comment: @mitch: I understand that sequences of GUIDs are predictable as they are based on local counter values, clock ticks and other 'local' machine factors. This narrows the entropy of GUID sequences significantly to far less than the bit count would suggest and yes, you would need to have access to prior information/GUIDs. I am not saying they are easily predictable, but it should be noted they are designed to be unique and not necessarily random, although they may appear to be. Others, far more competant than I, have suggested so elsewhere. If the app demands it, don't rely on pure GUIDs alone.