# How significantly decreased is the entropy of rand() ^ rand()?

Tags: random, cryptography

Assuming a language-agnostic setup in which the `rand()` function has a flawless implementation and returns a very large (let's say 128 bits), strong random unsigned integer, I should have fairly low chances of getting the same number twice considering the period of the RNG would be astronomically huge.

```
a = rand(); // very very low chances of getting twice the same number
```

However, if I XOR two such random integers, how significantly is the entropy of the oputput decreased? In other words, how worse are the chances that such a function:

```
def xorRand(): return rand() ^ rand();
```

returns twice the same number, compared to my hypothetical `rand()` alone?

Comment: Why would you do that? I doubt the entrophy will get any better from that (if so, the generator would already do it, wouldn't it?), so it wouldn't be useful for a PRNG either.

Comment: I know the entropy can't be increased and I suspect it would be worse, and as such I wouldn't do that. I'm simply wondering _how worse_ it would be. It's more a theoretical issue than a practical issue.

Comment: Like everything in probability, the odds are 50:50: It either happens, or it doesn't.

Comment: @Marc Therefore, since everyone is either killed by a freak badger attack or not, 50% of people are killed by badgers.

Comment: Those badgers can get very angry when suddenly confronted with a mushroom...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `rand()` function is a good implementation as you said, there's no difference between using `rand()` or `xorRand()` except that the latter takes twice the time.

If all of the 128 output bits are used, `rand()` will return each number with the same probability, so it will have chance 1:2**128 to return the same number as before. Same for `xorRand()`, as the XOR function is "symmetric" and returns equally distributed outputs for two equally distributed inputs.

This will only change if you either use a bad `rand()` implementation or a different "assymetric" operator like AND.

Note that using `xorRand()` often will even *improve* entropy for bad `rand()` implementations, f.e. think of a `rand()` that alternately returns a good random number and 0.

By the way, if you want to prevent your random function to generate the same number twice, do it yourself, f.e. by using a shuffle algorithm. There are many SO questions and answers that deal with this (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693880/create-random-number-sequence-with-no-repeats)).

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you had a 1-bit PRNG. The possible outcomes are:

```
1 ^ 1  -> 0
1 ^ 0  -> 1
0 ^ 1  -> 1
0 ^ 0  -> 0
```

So it looks to me as if it makes no difference.

Comment: Well reasoned. For what it's worth, I came to the same conclusion after reading the question (although my proof isn't nearly as simple).