# Iterate over the IPv4 address space or CIDR in a random order

Tags: python, networking, ip, ipv4, cidr

I've been searching for this for a while, i didn't even found this question been asked before.
So, i'm looking for a method to iterate over the IPv4 address space or CIDR in a nice random order without worrying of duplication. 
I've seen this implemented in [Zmap](https://github.com/zmap/zmap)

Comment: Is Zmap good enough for you?

Comment: Just generate random addresses and check if they've been visited before. Theres nothing special about IP addresses compared to integers in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Random Number Sequence with No Repeats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693880/create-random-number-sequence-with-no-repeats)

Answer (score 0):

you could start use something like:

```
import random
r = random.randrange
ip = "{}.{}.{}.{}".format(r(0,255),r(0,255),r(0,255),r(0,255))
```

however you should still check if the IP is valid. i.e. filter 0.0.0.0 and so on