# Generating non-repeating random numbers in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to generate non-repeating random numbers.  Please help me identify the problem in my code and how to fix it.

```
package number;

public class name {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int counter=0;
        boolean flag=true;
        int number=0;
        int a[] = new int[16];
        try
        {
            while(counter<16)
            {
                while(flag)
                {                           
                    number = (int)(Math.random()*16);
                    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                    if(a[i]==number)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        System.out.println(""+i+ "===="+ number);
                        a[counter]=number;  
                        flag= false;
                    }       
                }
                for(int i1=0;i1<16;i1++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<16;j++)
                    {
                        if(a[i1]==a[j])
                        {
                        }
                        else
                            System.out.print(" \t "+a[i1]);
                    }
                }
            }
            counter --;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish.  What are you having trouble with, and more specifically, what do you mean by "non repeating"?

Comment: I'm reminded of a [Dilbert: Tour of Accounting](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25) and [xkcd: 221](http://www.xkcd.com/221/).

Comment: Related (different language, but principles are the same): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693880/create-random-number-sequence-with-no-repeats?rq=1

Comment: There is repeating the (Random)number.

Comment: There are multiple problems with your code.  I'm not sure what the double `for` loop is intended to accomplish, but it is almost certainly not doing what you want it to do, and is probably in the wrong place.  However, I think the best thing is for you to debug the code yourself, either by using a debugger or by putting some `System.out.println` calls in the code to see if the variables are what you think they should be at certain key points.  (You may need to know about [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-)).

Comment: it hangs when i run it.

Comment: You need to think more about what you're trying to do.  A sequence that is constrained to not repeat is by definition *not* random.

Comment: You want to sort the numbers from 1-16 in random order?

Answer (score 2):

You're changing the `counter` variable outside the `while(counter<16)` loop and you should increment counter `counter++` instead of decrementing it.