# Evenly distributed random numbers relatively prime to 2

Tags: language-agnostic, discrete-mathematics, random

### A specific example

I need to generate a random number between 0 and 2, inclusive. (or choose randomly between -1, 0, and 1).

The naive approach would be to do something like `rand() mod 3` where `rand()` returns an integer.  This approach will not generate statistically random numbers unless the upper bound of `rand()` is not relatively prime (and the lower bound is 0).

For instance, assuming rand() returned 2 bits (from 0 to 3, inclusive), the modulus would map:

0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 0

This skew toward 0 would obviously be much less if more bits would be returned, but regardless, the skew would remain.

### The generic question

Is there a way of generating an evenly distributed random number between 0 and n-1, inclusive, where n is relatively prime to 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common approach is to discard random values above the last full cycle, and just ask for a new random number.

Answer (score 2):

It might help choosing your rand() upper bound to be k*n where k is an integer. This way the outcome will be evenly distributed provided that rand() is a good random generator.

If it's not possible to reduce the upper bound, you can pick k so that k*n is as close to rand() upper bound as possible and discard the results above this number trying again.

Answer (score 1):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464476/generating-shuffled-range-using-a-prng-rather-than-shuffling/467767#467767) to a similar question.

Basically, use your RNG and discard everything above N and try again. For optimization, you can use mod, and discard everything above n * floor(MAX / n)

Answer (score 0):

Generic Answer: You need to use more than just 2 bits of the number.

My rule of thumb is to generate floating-point values, *x*, 0.0 <= *x* < 1.0, multiply by 3 and truncate.  That should get you values in the range 0, 1 and 2 that depend on a larger number of bits.

Comment: Underneath, you are still exposing a small amount of bias in the fact that you are using a floating point number (31 bits of data mapping to 3 unique values)

Comment: Less than the astronomical bias from trying to map 4 values (2 bits) to 2 values.  Since most RNG's are 48 bits of actual randomness, your bias should be microscopic.  How often will you generate the billions of numbers required to measure the bias?