# Randomize files output in folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, random

How do I randomize the order of the files I get out of:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("folder");
```

Thank you! :-)

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816534/random-playlist-algorithm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use `Random`:

```
Random rng = new Random();
```

and then:

```
var randomOrderFiles = files.OrderBy(f => rng.Next());
```

This isn't the most efficient method as it takes O(nlogn). If this is a problem for you, better algorithms exist.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use Linq the following method should work:

```
static Random rand = new Random();
static void Randomize<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    for (int i = list.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int i2 = rand.Next(i + 1);
        if (i2 != i)
        {
            T tmp = list[i2];
            list[i2] = list[i];
            list[i] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: aka [Fisher–Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) - this can be done in-place (as you did), and has complexity of O(n).

Answer (score 2):

A [Fisher-Yates-Durstenfeld shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) is O(n) and should give unbiased distribution.

Create a helper/extension method to [perform an in-place shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5589250/55847) on the array returned from `GetFiles`:

```
// uses ShuffleInPlace extension from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5589250/55847
var arrayOfFiles = Directory.GetFiles("folder");
arrayOfFiles.ShuffleInPlace();
```

If you prefer to return a new sequence -- à la LINQ -- you could create a suitable [`Shuffle` extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653204/55847) instead:

```
// uses Shuffle extension from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653204/55847
var sequenceOfFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles("folder").Shuffle();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate over the source list.
2. Remove a random source item from the source list
3. Append removed item to a result list
4. Repeat until the source list is empty

```
List<string> files = Directory.GetFiles("folder");
List<string> result = new List<string>();

while (files.Count > 0)
{
  int n = IntegerUtility.Random(files.Count);
  string file = files.Remove(n);
  result.Add(file);
} 
return result;
```