# Shuffling string list in C# Windows phone 7

Tags: c#, arrays, list, windows-phone-7, shuffle

I've looked everywhere on how to shuffle/randomize a string list in C# for the windows phone 7. I'm still a beginner you could say so this is probably way out of my league, but I'm writing a simple app, and this is the base of it. I have a list of strings that I need to shuffle and output to a text block. I have bits and pieces of codes I've looked up, but I know I have it wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+shuffle

Comment: If you don't need the shuffling to be random, one simple option is to return "strings.OrderBy( s => s.GetHashCode() );" ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Is using Random and OrderBy a good shuffle algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/c-is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm)

Answer (score 3):

The [Fisher-Yates-Durstenfeld shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) is a proven technique that's easy to implement. Here's an extension method that will perform an in-place shuffle on any `IList<T>`.

(It should be easy enough to adapt if you decide that you want to leave the original list intact and return a new, shuffled list instead, or to [act on `IEnumerable<T>` sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651619/optimal-linq-query-to-get-a-random-sub-collection-shuffle/1653204#1653204), à la LINQ.)

```
var list = new List<string> { "the", "quick", "brown", "fox" };
list.ShuffleInPlace();

// ...

public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void ShuffleInPlace<T>(this IList<T> source)
    {
        source.ShuffleInPlace(new Random());
    }

    public static void ShuffleInPlace<T>(this IList<T> source, Random rng)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (rng == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("rng");

        for (int i = 0; i < source.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            int j = rng.Next(i, source.Count);

            T temp = source[j];
            source[j] = source[i];
            source[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now how would you go about setting a random string from the list to a textblock?

Comment: If you only need a single random string then perhaps you don't really need to shuffle the list at all; simply pick a random string from the existing list: `var rng = new Random(); yourTextBlock.Text = yourStringList[rng.Next(yourStringList.Length)];`