# my shuffle string[] not working?

Tags: c#, .net

I tried to write a shuffle string array algo but I get a null reference error.. I can't figure out why..

```
public static string[] arrRandomized;
public static string[] ShuffleWords(string[] Words)
{
    Random generator = new Random();
    for (int i=0;i < Words.Length; i++) {
        int pos = generator.Next(Words.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(Words[pos]); // I SEE RANDOM ITEM
        Console.Read(); // NULL REFERENCE ERROR AFTER THIS
        if (Words[pos] != null)
        {
            arrRandomized[i] = Words[pos];
            //remove item at pos so I get no duplicates
            Words[pos] = null;
        }
    }
```

I don't want to use ArrayList, i have my reasons but thats off topic I just want to know how come this isn't working :/ thanks

Comment: Where are you using Console.Read() ?

Comment: Changing a collection (or array) while iterating over it is inadvisable.

Comment: *"I can't figure out why.."* **Debug it.**

Comment: Pay special attention to `arrRandomized` also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9558461/932418

Comment: @Vaibhav Desai is just used to pause it, removing that makes no difference..

Comment: @codesparkle I have, and that's why i'm now here.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should initialize `arrRandomized`:

```
arrRandomized = new string[Words.Length];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your arrRandomized is never intialized. I would also recommend that you return an array rather then use a static reference because the subsequent calls to the method will change all references to the arrRandomized.

```
public static string[] ShuffleWords(string[] Words)
{    
    string[] arrRandomized = new string[Words.Length];
    Random generator = new Random();
    for (int i=0;i < Words.Length; i++) 
    {
        int pos = generator.Next(Words.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(Words[pos]); // I SEE RANDOM ITEM
        Console.Read(); // NULL REFERENCE ERROR AFTER THIS
        if (Words[pos] != null)
        {
            arrRandomized[i] = Words[pos];
            //remove item at pos so I get no duplicates
            Words[pos] = null;
        }
    }
    return arrRandomized;
}
```

Comment: got ridd of the error, but now the return array only has 2 items instead of 4.. the other 2 are there but empty :/