# How Destroy Sorting Of A Sorted List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, sorting, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Randomize a List<T> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp)

i have two lists like below :

```
List<strig> LS1 = new List<string>();
List<strig> LS1 = new List<string>();
```

LS1 have 5000 items inside.
LS2 is empty.
LS1 is a sorted list Ascending.
now i want to an shuffle list(created from LS1) and add that list to LS2!(totally shuffle)
what is the best way for doing that?

Comment: What do you mean unsorted? Do you want to shuffle it?

Comment: How do you unsort something?  Do you mean randomize the order?  What you're asking for doesn't make much sense.  A list is always in some kind of sorted order -- order of insertion into the list, for example.  Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Define "unsorted". Technically, if you just swap the first and second elements, the list is now unsorted.

Comment: Do you want to shuffle it? YES

Comment: if you just swap the first and second elements, the list is now unsorted.  -> it's not enough -> i want a totally shuffle list

Comment: Do you mean randomize the order -> YES

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp

Comment: Here you are : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp

Comment: Check this stackoverflow answer that uses Fischer-Yates shuffle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var LS2 = LS1.OrderBy(_ => rnd.Next()).ToList();
```

But better use this  [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557883/random-plot-algorithm)