# Generating unique random numbers except from a specific one in C

Tags: c, random

I was wondering, how can I generate unique random numbers except from a specific one. For example, if I want to generate numbers in range `1 to 10 except from 3`, the output should be something like this:

```
7 6 1 2 4 9 5 8 10
```

Comment: I think for random number the output "could" rather than "should".

Comment: As an aside - unique and random are not compatible.  A random choice has the same probability of selecting 8 regardless of the fact that the number 8 was just previously selected. Most of the answers given already will provide duplicates.  You want a deck (as in deck of cards) shuffling algorithm.  @Joni's answer is the only shuffle I've seen so far.

Comment: Fisher-Yates' or Floyd's algorithms suit here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unique random numbers in O(1)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-random-numbers-in-o1).  There are other similar questions where the appropriate answer is "Fisher-Yates" including [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795004/random-numbers-which-have-not-been-previously-chosen/18795053#18795053) which was just closed yesterday as a duplicate.

Comment: You are looking to generate a random permutation of the input numbers.

Comment: @jimmcnamara That's not correct.  Conditional probabilities that shift the likelihood of outcomes based on prior/other outcomes are an integral part of probability theory.  The "birthday problem" calculations that describe the likelihood of hash collisions work out that way precisely because each new number decreases the available pool of values which can avoid a collision.

Comment: I have updated my answer. See the code.

Comment: @pjs - Yes. But a discrete random variable, depending on probability density, has an equal chance of generating any given result. See: [Random variable](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/ranvar.htm).  The OP wanted a shuffling algorithm or a random permutation of a set.  We are arguing definitions, which is okay. Comments are not well suited to this.  In a sense you are correct, mathematically.  But PNRG's in C POSIX-standard libraries are as I described -- like rand() or lrand48().  The answers I saw used rand() and company, and potentially provided duplicates.

Comment: @jimmcnamara I agree that OP wants shuffling. I'm disputing your initial two sentences. You can have that the conditional probability of generating an 8 is zero given that an 8 has already occurred. PRNGs are as you described, but random variables are not.  For random variables, discrete does not imply equiprobable. That's why people who work in this simulation methodology distinguish between random numbers (which are uniformly distributed) and random variates, which are everything else and are generally derived from RNs

Answer (score 4):

Shuffle the numbers 1 - 10 and remove 3.

It doesn't matter if you remove the 3 before or after shuffling.

Alternatively, shuffle the numbers 1 - 9 and relabel 3 as 10...

For shuffling without bias you can use for example the Fisher-Yates algorithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Answer (score 2):

Generate random number in the range 1..9 and add one if the number is greater than or equal to 3.

Comment: This wouldn't give a uniform distribution however. EDIT: I am an idiot, ignore this.

Comment: @JamesElderfield: How so? Would you not be equally likely to get 10 as you would be to get 1?

Comment: Oh sorry you are right I take that back, brain skipped the "or more" part.

Comment: @JamesElderfield Edited my answer it might help brains to get the meaning of my sentence ;)

Comment: @JamesElderfield Don't know what's with this answer. Had the same thought as you in first comment:)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Generate a number. Check its value, if the number is 3 generate another one. If it isn't 3 then use it.</strike>

EDIT: Thinking before coffee is a terrible plan. If you want to get every number in the range in a random order then I agree with the others talking about shuffling lists. If however you want some random subset of the range I would store a list of forbidden values. Shuffling and only taking the first *n* numbers would also be suitable if the range isn't very large (e.g. not something like 0<x<INT_MAX).

Every time you generate a number check if the generated number is on the forbidden list and if it is, generate another number. Every time you generate a valid number you add it to the list to ensure generated numbers are unique. The list should also be initialised with your unwanted numbers (3 in the example given).

Answer (score 0):

This code will generate unique random numbers from minimum to maximum of a given range.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{

    int max_range, min_range, i = 0, rand_num;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    printf("Enter your maximum of range: ");
    scanf("%d", &max_range);
    printf("Enter your minimum of range: ");
    scanf("%d", &min_range);
    bool digit_seen[max_range + 1]; // VLAs For C99 only 

    for (int i = min_range; i <= max_range; i++)
        digit_seen[i] = false;  

    for (;;)
    {  
         rand_num = rand() % max_range + min_range;
         if(rand_num !=3)
             if(!digit_seen[rand_num])
             {
                printf("%d ", rand_num);
                digit_seen[rand_num] = true;
                i++;
             }
         if( i == (max_range - 1) )
             exit(0);
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are generating way too much random numbers here. Imagine 8 of the 9 numbers are 'seen'-- you might have to generate dozens of numbers, just to (randomly!) stumble on the last one. Since you are already generating a list, do this instead: (1) pick a random number out of your list, (2) move the last item of your list to this position, (3) decrease length of the list. Repeat until list is empty.

Comment: @Jongware; I do not understand how your logic will work here? o.O

Comment: Your code will blindly keep on generating already-taken random numbers. You are better off to fill the list first (in this case, excluding the unwanted value) and then pick a random one *out of that list*. Once used, *remove* it from the list so it won't be chosen again. The rest is bookkeeping.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:-

```
unsigned int
randomnumber(unsigned int min, unsigned int max)
{
       double scaled = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;

       return (max - min +1)*scaled + min;
}
```

then later you can do this:-

```
 x = randomnumber(1,10);

if (x==3)
{ x = x+1;}
```

or

```
if (x!=3)
{ printf("%d",x)}
```

Comment: So, result "4" will be generated 2x often, than all another numbers?

Comment: @maxihatop:- That is just one approach. May be OP can change it as per his/her convenience.!!! Hope that makes sense!!

Comment: @maxihatop:- Updated my answer with what you may be pointing at!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer - returns random value in [min, max), except "except".

```
int myrand(int min, int max, int except) {
   int rc;
   do {
      rc = min + rand() % (max - min); 
   } while(rc == except);
   return rc;
}
```

Comment: I think `rc = min + rand() % (max - min)` will not print the `max` value.

Comment: Yes, you right. I stated above:  [min, max); This is standard math notation: [=including, )=excluding.