# openfiledialog file and directory?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I m trying to make simple mp3 player.when i use this

```
 listBox2.Items.Add(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

to add songs to my listbox it is working but it shows file directory so i changed like this

```
listBox2.Items.Add(openFileDialog1.SafeFileName);
```

then it looks song name on listbox1 but when i click play button it is not working:(

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication12222
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern long mciSendString(string strCommand, StringBuilder strReturn, int iReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback);
        public string Pcommand;
        public bool isOpen;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            Pcommand = "close MediaFile";
            mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            isOpen = false;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            Pcommand = "open \"" + listBox1.SelectedItem + "\" type mpegvideo alias MediaFile";
            mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            isOpen = true;
            Play(true);
        }

        private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Media File(*.mpg,*.dat,*.avi,*.wmv,*.wav,*.mp3)|*.wav;*.mp3;*.mpg;*.dat;*.avi;*.wmv";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (openFileDialog1.FileName != ""){

               // listBox1.Items.Add(openFileDialog1.SafeFileName);

                listBox2.Items.Add(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Start();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stop();
        }
        public void Play(bool loop)
        {
            if (isOpen)
            {
                Pcommand = "play MediaFile";
                if (loop)
                    Pcommand += " REPEAT";
                mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            }
        }
        int x;
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (listBox1.SelectedIndex ==listBox1.Items.Count-1 ) { x++; }
            else
            {
                Stop();
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1;

                Start();
            }
        }
        int y;
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (listBox1.SelectedIndex ==0) { y++; }
            else
            {
                Stop();
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex - 1;

                Start();
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

            Stop();
            Start();
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
            Stop();
            Start();
        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            Pcommand = "close MediaFile";
            mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            isOpen = false;
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

extra question is it possible to mix (random) a listbox .I add songs on mp3 player then when i want to click mix button i want list mixed.Is there any listbox command for this?

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom class:

```
public class FileItem
{
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
}
```

And then create a new instance of this class when you get a file from the `OpenFileDialog`, save the `openFileDialog1.FileName` to `FilePath` property, and then get the short file name using the `Windows.IO.Path.GetFileName()` method.

Rather than adding the file path to the `ListBox` directly from the `OpenFileDialog`, add this instance of your class.

And change the `DisplayMember` property of your `ListBox` to `"ShortName"`, this way the "short name" of your file path will be displayed in the `ListBox`.

Comment: extra question is it possible to mix (random) a listbox .I add songs on mp3 player then when i want to click mix button i want list mixed.Is there any listbox command for this?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/1287572/494094. Jon Skeet provides a nice implementation of Knuth-Fisher-Yates Shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the link below to shuffle your playlist.

[Random playlist algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816534/random-playlist-algorithm)

Thanks,
Naval