# How to generate a list of shuffled integers between 2 numbers?

Tags: c#, random, shuffle, prng

I want to create a shuffled set of integers such that:

1. Given the same seed, the shuffle will be the same every time
2. As I iterate through, every number in the shuffled set will be used exactly once before repeating itself
3. Will work for large sets (I want all numbers between 0 and 2 billion)
4. Will generate between a range, for example, 100 to 150.

This option gives a great solution if you want, say, all of the numbers between 0 and a specified number: [Generating Shuffled Range Using a PRNG Rather Than Shuffling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464476/generating-shuffled-range-using-a-prng-rather-than-shuffling)

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just use the solutions you likened to and shift the results by the minimum? So, for 100–150, that would be something like `GenerateSequence(50).Select(i => i + 100)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the exact same algorithm as the linked question. Just generate numbers between 0 and `upperBound - lowerBound + 1` and add `lowerBound` to the result.

e.g. (using code from linked question):

```
var upper = 5;
var lower = 3;
foreach (int n in GenerateSequence(upper-lower+1))
{
    Console.WriteLine(n+lower);
}
```

If you want the sequence to repeat (shuffled differently each time), you can add a `while (true)` around the iterator method body.