# I want to roll 3 dice with independent numbers from each other

Tags: python, random

I want to write a python program that will simulate 3 dice being rolled at the same time but I want the 3 dice to always have a different number from each other every time they are rolled. ex on the first roll I get 2,1,6 that is fine but I dont want the prog. to ever roll duplicates for ex 2,4,2. (3,3,3, would also be unacceptable)

```
# generating random numbers 1 - 6
die1 = random.randint(1, 6) 

die2 = random.randrange(1, 6)

die3 = random.randrange(1, 6)
```

this is all I have so far, im a beginner ... Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this question if you are interested in the algorithm itself as well, rather than only in the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311703/algorithm-for-sampling-without-replacement

Comment: Note: *independent* in this context is usually understood to mean that the outcome of one die doesn't affect the outcome of the others. That's almost the exact opposite of what you want. I think the word you are looking for is *distinct*.

Answer (score 8):

Try [`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
>>> sides = 6
>>> dice = random.sample(range(1, sides + 1), 3)
[3, 6, 1]
```

I'd advise that you reconsider whether it is a good idea to have variables called `die1`, `die2`, `die3`.

It is usually better to use a list as in the above example.

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
a = range(1,7)
random.shuffle(a)
a[:3]
```

Comment: Nice approach. Much better than rolling three independent dice and then re-rolling the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

A simplistic approach would be

```
import random
die1, die2, die3 = random.sample([1,2,3,4,5,6], 3)
```

[Random Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the usual behaviour of three dice, but you could do:

```
import random
[die1, die2, die3] = random.sample(xrange(1, 7), 3)
```

Here's the documentation on [`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample) and [`xrange()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=range#xrange) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to roll multiple times, is better to store the range(1,7) somewhere and use the sample function instead of the shuffle one (obvously because 'shuffle' shuffles all the range)

take a look on this:

```
import random,time
N=80000
a = range(1,7)
t= time.clock()
for i in xrange(N):
    random.shuffle(a)
    a[:3]
t= time.clock()-t
print t

t= time.clock()
for i in xrange(N):
    dice = random.sample(range(1, 6 + 1), 3)
t= time.clock()-t
print t

t= time.clock()
for i in xrange(N):
    dice = random.sample(a, 3)
t= time.clock()-t
print t
```