# choose uniqe item from list

Tags: c#, wpf, random

I have this list of colors in a `wpf` application.
what I want is to random choose a color each time I call the function but I don’t want that a one color be chosen more than on time. 
This is my code that not doing what I want.

```
 var polyline = new MapPolyline();
 polyline.Stroke = GetRandomPolylineColor();

private Brush GetRandomPolylineColor()
        {
            var brushes = new Brush[] 
            {       Brushes.Blue,
                 Brushes.Black,
                 Brushes.Red,
                 Brushes.Brown,
                 Brushes.Green,
                 Brushes.HotPink,
                 Brushes.Khaki,
                 Brushes.IndianRed,
                 Brushes.LimeGreen,
                 Brushes.Orange                               
            };

            var rnd = new Random();
            return brushes[rnd.Next(brushes.Length)];
        }
```

Comment: Is  your code currently swapping the color? or is that also one of the problems? if it changes all you should need is to make a temp variable for ur current brush, then check it for equality and go again if its the same as before

Comment: Id probably have used lists and had a master list, aka master_brushes and set brushes to the same content, and then each time picked from brushes, removed the used item, on finding 0 items, reload from master and start over again.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is known as sampling without replacement. This has been answered in the SO posts [Unique (non-repeating) random numbers in O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-non-repeating-random-numbers-in-o1#196065) and [Algorithm for sampling without replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311703/algorithm-for-sampling-without-replacement).