# Random objects to a list without repetition

Tags: c#, list, object, random, repeat

I have a little problem over here. I have a list of questions `KlausimuList` and i have to form another list `Atsitiktinis` witch would be a random length and would have random questions taken from `KlausimuList`. My method works, but the problem is - questions are duplicating. Could you please write me a code where they don't? I have an idea of making a seperate int array of indexes of questions i already added, and then each time check if that question already is in that list. If it does - genererate a new number, but i just don't know how to write the code for this thing :D. Thanks in advice. Code is in c#.

```
static void FormuotiAtsisiktini(List<Klausimas> KlausimuList, ref List<Klausimas> Atsitiktinis)
    {
        Random kiek = new Random();
        int kiekis = kiek.Next(1, KlausimuList.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < kiekis; i++)
            Atsitiktinis.Add(KlausimuList[kiek.Next(1, KlausimuList.Count)]);
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at `HashSet`, it won't allow duplicates to be added: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb353005(v=vs.110).aspx. Or create a copy of your original list and remove the used items from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `HashSet` to avoid duplicates. `Add` method on `HashSet` returns `false` when try adding duplicate item.

```
static void FormuotiAtsisiktini(List<Klausimas> KlausimuList, ref List<Klausimas> Atsitiktinis)
{
     Random kiek = new Random();
    int kiekis = kiek.Next(1, KlausimuList.Count);

    HashSet<Klausimas> hashset= new HashSet<Klausimas>();

    for (int i = 0; i < kiekis;)
    {
        i+=  hashset.Add(KlausimuList[kiek.Next(1, KlausimuList.Count)])?  1:0; // returns true when successfully added.
    }

    Atsitiktinis = hashset.ToList();            
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks! :)

Comment: It would probably make more sense to return a list and not have the ref parameter.  I know that's how the OP was but it's still a little weird

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It creates a copy of the original list and removes the already taken items from it:

```
static List<Klausimas> FormuotiAtsisiktini(List<Klausimas> KlausimuList)
{
  Random kiek = new Random();

  List<Klausimas> source = new List<Klausimas>(KlausimuList);
  List<Klausimas> result = new List<Klausimas>();
  int kiekis = kiek.Next(1, KlausimuList.Count);
  for (int i = 0; i < kiekis; i++)
  {
    var match = source[kiek.Next(0, source.Count - 1)];
    result.Add(match);
    source.Remove(match);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called sampling without replacement, and a solution to that is provided in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311703/algorithm-for-sampling-without-replacement). Furthermore, to ensure that you are actually adding duplicates to your collection, consider using a `HashSet` instead of a `List`.