# What is the runtime of operations on Java's Arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, runtime, complexity-theory

It seems like there is no official benchmarks for some of the very commonly used classes, for example [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

I could not find the documentation on the runtime for insert or remove. Compared to Python's [List](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), which is similar to ArrayList, there is a well documented runtime complexity (see link above).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101789/why-does-javas-arraylists-remove-function-seem-to-cost-so-little), gave some somewhat detailed benchmark on removing and copying elements from an ArrayList, but it still doesn't give the exact complexity analysis. I'm working on a project which takes extremely long data (~500,000 data points) so I can't sit back and assume removing or inserting data from ArrayList operates in constant time like magic. **Where can I find this information?**

Comment: Why don't you start by reading about how `List` implementations work in java. Then run your own benchmarks with your use cases.

Comment: Looking at the implementation is the best solution imho

Comment: Straight from the javadoc: *The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run in constant time. The add operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking). The constant factor is low compared to that for the LinkedList implementation.*

Comment: Or this cheat sheet http://www.coderfriendly.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/java_collections_v2.pdf and this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559839/big-o-summary-for-java-collections-framework-implementations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some quick references of Java complexities:

- http://www.coderfriendly.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/java_collections_v2.pdf
- http://infotechgems.blogspot.com/2011/11/java-collections-performance-time.html

But really, nothing beats looking to the source, which can be found [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7-gate/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java).

---

Regarding the particular question of adding to an ArrayList, for example, we can see:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
           ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
           elementData[size++] = e;
           return true;
       }
```

The complexity for this operation clearly depends on *ensureCapacityInternal*:

```
private void ensureCapacityInternal(int minCapacity) {
               modCount++;
               // overflow-conscious code
               if (minCapacity - elementData.length > 0)
                   grow(minCapacity);
           }
```

Which depends on *grow*:

```
private void grow(int minCapacity) {
           // overflow-conscious code
           int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
           int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
           if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
               newCapacity = minCapacity;
           if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
               newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
           // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
           elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
       }
```

So we can see that the grow operation happens conditionally, and that in many cases, adding will be an O(1) operation.  But you can also see from this the details of *when* the array will grow.

Comment: That's not very helpful - it doesn't cover the complexities of collection complexity. For example that a `LinkedList` never has to expand to so `add` always takes the same constant time whereas for an `ArrayList` there sometimes needs to be a `System.arraycopy` call.

Comment: Yes, like I said, it's good to have an understanding of how the collection implementation works.  Still, I feel that such a reference is helpful, because it is somewhat analogous to the example list the OP provided for Python list.

Comment: To allow for understanding of what actually happens for the different ArrayList operations, I've provided a link to ArrayList source.

Comment: Which source is that? i remeber an different ArrayList implementation, especilly in grow i remember a System.arraycopy.