# How can I put the Gallery image into the Edit Text Randomly using drawable

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable, android-gallery

In my app I am try to get the Gallery images into the Edit Text randomly , I need like a chat application we can type any text inside the Edit Text also we need to add Gallery images and emoticons, where ever the user need can select and put into the Edit Text have any idea.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I have try this code for this link http://hardiknadiyapara.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-chat-application.html

Comment: In that code i can take the gallery image but i can not take randomly also i will appear on the right corner

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470509/how-to-set-random-images-to-imageviews

Comment: This link useful for the image view but i have used the edit text alone

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this question : [StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/get-pick-an-image-from-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically/4470069#4470069)

It uses something like this :

```
b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01))
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
                // select a file
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have try this code too but edit text image will appear in right side corner please guide me

Comment: This code is not useful for put images into the edit text, kindly send me useful answers.

Comment: Image to a EditText? That's like writing the synthesis of Benzene in a Mathematics Exam.

Answer (score 1):

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341702/displaying-emoticons-in-android/4302199#4302199)

you should use Spannable strings and parsing your emoticons!!!

Comment: i have use this link for images http://hardiknadiyapara.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-chat-application.html

Comment: In that code i can take the gallery image but i can not take randomly also i will appear on the right corner

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
int position = Selection.getSelectionStart(AgendaWriterEditText.this.getText());

Spanned e = Html.fromHtml("<img src=\"" + imageResource + "\">", imageGetter, null);
// String s2 = Html.toHtml(e);
// Log.w("Agenda", "Before DB->Image is: " + s2);

AgendaWriterEditText.this.getText().insert(position, e);
```

**Thanks everyone for your reply**

I have solved the issue by getting the image from the gallery and insert inside the edit text with the code above and the method to get the drawable is

```
// setting image
    holder.dwEdit.setImageGetter(new Html.ImageGetter() {
        @Override
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            Drawable drawable = null;

            try {

                // declaring views
                ImageView topicImage = new ImageView(_context);
                // setting data
                topicImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(source));

                // getting Drawable from image to use in HTML <img tag
                drawable = topicImage.getDrawable();

                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

                drawable = new BitmapDrawable(_context.getResources(),
                        bitmap);

                // Important
                if (drawable != null) {
                    // setting the bounds (width + height)
                    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Hammad", "Failed to load inline image!");
            }
            return drawable;
        }
    });
```

**Important**

this method is called when edit text read the  tag and it give src="path" to this method and that code will return Drawable

Finally image can be added to edit text field