# android - generate random numbers with no repeat

Tags: java, random

can anyone please tell me how to generate random numbers with no repeat 
example

random (10) should(may) return  3,4,2,1,7,6,5,8,9,10 with no repeat

Thanks

Comment: it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040001/java-creating-random-numbers-with-no-duplicates

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would suggest adding the numbers to an `ArrayList<Integer>` and then use `Collections.shuffle()` to randomize their order. Something like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) number.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(number);
```

Comment: liked it! a question, if i execute Collection.Shuffle twice or thrice  will it provide different order?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it will. I can't find a reason why it shouldn't. Easy enough to check though, eh? ;)

Answer (score 4):

Make a list of generated numbers, when your newly generated number is already in this list you make a new random number.

```
Random rng = new Random(); // Ideally just create one instance globally
List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < numbersNeeded; i++)
{
    while(true)
    {
        Integer next = rng.nextInt(max) + 1;
        if (!generated.contains(next))
        {
            // Done for this iteration
            generated.add(next);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this method doesn't scale very well

Answer (score 2):

My two cents

```
public Collection<Integer> getRandomSubset(int max,int count){
    if(count > max){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i =  0 ; i < count ;i++){
        list.add(i);
    }       
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    return list.subList(0, count);
}
```

Comment: I like the `subList()` enhancement in this solution - great for dealing out a hand of cards from a deck

Answer (score -2):

If there are only a few numbers, less than 100, I think I solution could be create a boolean array and once you get a number, set the position of the array to true. I don't think that it takes long time until all the numbers appear. Hope it helps!

Cheers!