# Repeated images beeing retrieved from my Firebase DB query

Tags: java, android

In my `CardStackFragment` I have a query that retrieves information on my "paises" child from the **Firebase Realtime Database**. This basically retrieves **4** things: `Image Url`, `Country Name`, `Country Continent`, `Country Spoken Language` for each country that is registered in my DB.
This is the code:

```
countriesRef.removeEventListener(this);
            List<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> nomePaisList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> continenteList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> linguaList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                String url = ds.child("Imagem").getValue(String.class); 
                String nomePais = ds.child("Nome").getValue(String.class); 
                String continente = ds.child("Continente").getValue(String.class);
                String lingua = ds.child("Língua").getValue(String.class);
                    urlList.add(url);
                    nomePaisList.add(nomePais); 
                    continenteList.add(continente);
                    linguaList.add(lingua);
            }           
            int urlCount = urlList.size();

            int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(urlCount);
            final List<String> randomUrlList = new ArrayList<>();
            final List<String> randomNomePaisList = new ArrayList<>();
            final List<String> randomContinenteList = new ArrayList<>();
            final List<String> randomLinguaList = new ArrayList<>();


            for (int i=0; i<=Constants.TOTAL_PAISES; i++)
            {

                    randomUrlList.add(urlList.get(randomNumber));
                    randomNomePaisList.add(nomePaisList.get(randomNumber));
                    randomContinenteList.add(continenteList.get(randomNumber));
                    randomLinguaList.add(linguaList.get(randomNumber));
                    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(randomUrlList.get(i)).into(imgFotoPais); 

                        txtPaisNome.setText(randomNomePaisList.get(i)); 
                        imgFotoPais2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txtPaisNome.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                        }

        }
```

I then add it to a **random list** to make appear different countries that appeared last time, when the user refreshes...
The problem is that, my `Random` function can generate a number that has been already generated before so in my 5 ImageViews, more than one can have the same image. How can I validate the `Random` function to generate only numbers that is hasn't generated previously?

**EDIT**
`Collections.shuffle(number);` is **NOT** an option!

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7725078/7505436) for generating unique random numbers

Comment: I could use `Collections.shuffle(number);` but, for example, if I have an image of Portugal I need, in my nameList, the name "Portugal" too. Using that `Collections.shuffle(number);` it would shuffle all the lists randomly and then I could get the image of Portugal but the name of other country...

Comment: ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i <=urlCount ; ++i) number.add(i);
int randomNumber = Collections.shuffle(number);

Comment: I get this error
Incompatible types.
Required:
int
Found:
void

When trying to do `int randomNumber`...