# Generate random numbers less than 9

Tags: android, random

I want to generate random number in two field between range 1-8 and also field sum should be less than 9.
what I've done done till now

```
for (int i; i <= 6; i++) {
    fieldOne = rand.nextInt(9 - 5) + 5;
    fieldTwo = rand.nextInt(9 - 5) + 5;
    fieldSum = fieldOne + fieldTwo;
    System.out.print(fieldSum); // should be < 9 and not repetition
}
```

but `fieldSum` become greater then 9 so **How it is control this condition?
And Sequence should be random should not repeat 2 or more time**.

Comment: How the sum can be < 9 if you are adding 2 values which are >= 5?

Comment: @Adam i done one change 1-8 instead 5-8

Comment: If `fieldOne` is 8, then whatever value from 1-8 `fieldTwo` has, the sum will not be < 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rand.nextInt(9-5)` won't calculate a random number between 5 and 8, it will make the operation 9 minus 5 and then will calculate `rand.nextInt(4)`.

To calculate a random number between 5 and 8 you have to do something like this:

```
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    int rand1 = r.nextInt(4) + 5;

    int rand2 = r.nextInt(4) + 5;

    int result = rand1 + rand2;
    Log.v("", "" + result);
}
```

The problem is that result can't be < than 9 because you are summing two numbers that are => 5 so the lower result you can  get is 10.

Edit for a solution with no repetition:

```
private List<Integer> rdmNumList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

private final int leftLimitRange = 1;
private final int rightLimitRange = 10;

private final int numOfIteration = 10;

public void generateNumList() {
    for (int i = leftLimitRange; i <= rightLimitRange; i++) {
        this.rdmNumList.add(num);
    }
}

public int getRandomNumer() {
    Random r = new Random();
    int rNum = r.nextInt(rdmNumList.size());
    int result = this.rdmNumList.get(rNum);
    this.rdmNumList.remove(rNum);
    return result;
}

public void test() {
    this.generateNumList();
    if(this.numOfIteration <= ((this.rightLimitRange - this.leftLimitRange + 1))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.numOfIteration; i++) {
            Log.v("Debug Output", String.valueOf(this.getRandomNumer()));
        }
    }  
}
```

Note: this is efficient only with small range of number

This code works but it's far from being good. You should find some other solution by yourself. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040001/creating-random-numbers-with-no-duplicates) will help you find your way

Comment: result should not be same 2 or more time;

Comment: If you want that each number occurs only once you will need more number. From 10 to 16 you have only 7 numbers. If you run the code above for 10 times it's sure that you will have al least 3 number that occurs twice. To lower to 1 the occurrences of the numbers it's a bit more complex and the range for the rand1/2 calculation must be  => of 10 (the times you repeat the code contained in the for). If you are looking for something like this let me know and i'll post some code

Comment: @Raberto,Thanks to answer,I need only small range of number.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this --> random.nextInt()%9; another way Get random nuber with random.nextInt(9).

Answer (score 0):

Try,

fieldSum=(fieldOne+fieldTwo)%9;

This will def