# Fastest way to populate a grid with elements randomly

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have a grid: `int[][] the_grid = new int[4][4];` and I want to randomly populate it with elements ?, +, -, *, !, /, #, % such that exactly two squares have one of the elements in them. What's the most succinct and efficient way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand... are the elements *?, +, -, *, !, /, #, %* considered as `int`? Or is your grid actually a `String[][]` ?

Comment: Good puzzle.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4040031/2359488 this link shows how to generate random numbers without duplicates. If you populate a list containing 16 elements ( ?, +, -, *, !, /, #, % .. each twice), and then pop them back randomly into your grid, you'd get what you want.

Comment: Also, 2 more things: could it possibly be a `char[][]` array; and when you say *exactly two squares have one of the elements in them*, what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your grid actually contains `String`s (and not `int`s), I would simply:

**list** the tokens you can have:

```
final List<String> tokens = Arrays.asList("?", "+", "-", "*", "!", "/", "#", "%", "?", "+", "-", "*", "!", "/", "#", "%");
```

**shuffle** these tokens:

```
Collections.shuffle(tokens);
```

then finally **add** them while iterating over your grid:

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
for (final String token : tokens) {
    theGrid[i][j] = token;
    if (++j == 4) {
        j = 0;
        ++i;
    }
}
```

---

Complete example:

```
final String[][] theGrid = new String[4][4];
final List<String> tokens = Arrays.asList("?", "+", "-", "*", "!", "/", "#", "%", "?", "+", "-", "*", "!", "/", "#", "%");
Collections.shuffle(tokens);

int i = 0, j = 0;
for (final String token : tokens) {
    theGrid[i][j] = token;
    if (++j == 4) {
        j = 0;
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
for (final String[] row : theGrid) {
    for (final String column : row) {
        System.out.print(column);
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Sample output (changes every time):

```
?!!%
+*--
#/#%
*/?+
```