# Add unique random numbers to an integer array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I've created an ArrayList for integers which I would like to fill with 200 numbers. Each number can be within a range between 0 and 1023.

Therefore I've written this code:

```
Random rand = new Random();
ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

int START_AMOUNT = 200;

for(int i = 0; i < START_AMOUNT; 

  values.add(rand.nextInt(1024));      

}
```

As You might see, the for-loop will add 200 random numbers to the "values" ArrayList, from 0 to 1023. Now my problem is that I want the Array to have only unique numbers. How can I tell the Random class not to generate any numbers that already are existent in the ArrayList?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating Unique Random Numbers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115722/generating-unique-random-numbers-in-java)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040001/creating-random-numbers-with-no-duplicates

Comment: you don't tell the `Random` class to do anything - that would make it non-random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I'd do is creating an array of 1023 int composed by 1,2,3,...,1023. Then you shuffle it, and you take only the 200 first terms :

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 1; i <= 1023; i++)
{
    ints.add(i);
}

Collections.shuffle(ints);
```

**EDIT as suggested by @Bohemian♦**

```
List<Integer> result = ints.subList(0,200);
```

Comment: Lose everything after the first loop and use List.subList() instead: `ints = ints.subList(0, START_AMOUNT);`

Comment: I didn't want to make mistake because I can't remember well Lists manipulation. So this works and he have the idea, but yes sublist seems pretty nice.

Comment: Pretty nice idea, I remember having it done similiar to this, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
A Set is a Collection that cannot contain duplicate elements. 
It models the mathematical set abstraction. 
The Set interface contains only methods inherited from Collection 
and adds the restriction that duplicate elements are prohibited.
```

And therefore,

```
public boolean add(E e)
  Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present. 
  [...]
  If this set already contains the element, 
      the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false.
```

As such, what I'd do is use a Set, then add those to the list:

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
while(set.size() < 200) 
{
    set.add(rand.nextInt(1024)); 
}
values.addAll(set);
```

Comment: I agree, you should use a set to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Set:

```
Random rand = new Random();
Set<Integer> values = new HashSet<Integer>();
final int START_AMOUNT = 200;

while(values.size() < START_AMOUNT) { 
    values.add(rand.nextInt(1024));      
}
List<Integer> uniqueList = new ArrayList<Integer>(values);
System.out.println(uniqueList);
```

Comment: I was faster by 7 seconds, heheh.

Comment: What's the difference between using a Set or another List?

Comment: When you try to add an element into the `Set` using `add()` that is already contained by the `Set`, then the `add()` method will return false and not add the duplicate element.

Comment: See Zhuinden answer above. A Set cannot contain duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check if the ArrayList contains the given random number everytime you want to add one.

```
Random rand = new Random();
Integer r;
ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

int START_AMOUNT = 200;

for(int i = 0; i < START_AMOUNT; i++) {

  r = rand.nextInt(1024);
  If !values.contains(r) {
    values.add(r);
  } else {
   i--;
  }

}
```

Although i think Kabulan0lak's answer would be more performant if that is important.