# Generating random numbers in a particular range

Tags: java, android, random, secure-random

I am trying to generate `n` random numbers between 0-31 in my Android code.
Below is the code that I am using:

```
int max_range = 31;
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
int[] digestCodeIndicesArr = new int[indices_length];
int i = 0, random_temp = 0;

while (i != indices_length-1) {
    random_temp = secureRandom.nextInt(max_range);
    if (!Arrays.asList(digestCodeIndicesArr).contains(random_temp)) {
        digestCodeIndicesArr[i] = random_temp;
        i++;
    }
}
```

`indices_length` is the number of random numbers that I need. It's generally 6,7 or 9. But when I print the generated array, I generally end up seeing duplicates. Can someone point out the mistake I am making. I have added the below line of code to filter out random duplicates:

```
if (!Arrays.asList(digestCodeIndicesArr).contains(random_temp))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what exacly do you want to do? that the 9 nubers will be different? 'cause your code is ok for what you wrote in English. Random behaves like that: sometimes you throw the same number one after the other even with a dice.

Comment: Or duplicate of [Creating random numbers with no duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4040001/5221149), which has more description, and alternative for large valueset.

Comment: @Tunaki, we don't even know yet what does he want to achieve, how can you say it's a duplicate?

Comment: @Gavriel We do know, because OP said that "seeing duplicates" was a "mistake".

Comment: Or the mistake is that he doesn't understand that it happens once in a while

Comment: I do understand that getting duplicates is a possibility. For the same reason I added this line of code: if (!Arrays.asList(digestCodeIndicesArr).contains(random_temp)). so that if the array already contains the number being generated now, we will skip it

Comment: @Gavriel: The problem is not that the random number getting generated is a duplicate. I am confused as to how digestCodeIndicesArr is getting populated with a duplicate when I have the below condition:                            if (!Arrays.asList(digestCodeIndicesArr).contains(random_temp)). Shouldn't this condition filter out any duplicate random number being generated.

Comment: @Andreas: I am not saying that seeing duplicates is a mistake. I am confused as to how my array is getting populated with duplicates even when I have put a check for the same.

Comment: Thanks Sid. @Tunaki, I rest my case. This is not a duplicate IMHO

Comment: @Tunaki: I have edited my question. Hope that it makes you understand the problem that I am facing.

Comment: Fair enough, reopened.

Comment: Although the duplicate link that was provided by @Tunaki didn't tell you what you did wrong, it did actually tell you how to do it right. As explained in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35046336/5221149), your use of `Arrays.asList` was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(digestCodeIndicesArr)` does not produce a `List<Integer>` with `size() == digestCodeIndicesArr.length`.
It produces a `List<int[]>` with `size() == 1`, where first (and only) element is the array.
As such, it will never contain `random_temp`, so `! contains()` is always true.

It is bad for performance to constantly create a list and perform a sequential search to check for duplicates. Use a `Set` instead, that you maintain in parallel with the array, or use a `LinkedHashSet` first, then convert to array.

Anyway, this explains why your code wasn't working. The duplicate link that Tunaki had provided and the [duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4040001/5221149) I provided in comment, explains how to actually do what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change:

```
int[] digestCodeIndicesArr = new int[indices_length];
```

to:

```
Integer[] digestCodeIndicesArr = new Integer[indices_length];
```

because `Arrays.asList(digestCodeIndicesArr)` is `List<int[]>`, and not what you thought probably (`List<int>` or `List<Integer>` I guess).