# Generating random numbers in an array without any duplicate numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create an array with random number with length of 78.  I don't know how to search the entire array and check if last entry was duplicate and remove it.  Someone please help.

```
function initAll() {
var balls = LoadInBingoBalls();
for(i=0; i < balls.length;i++)
        {
            (balls[i]);
        }
    }

function setSquare (numSquare) {
    var BingoSquare = "square" + numSquare.toString();

    document.getElementById(BingoSquare).innerHTML  = RandomNumber(MaxNo);
}

var RandomNumber = function (max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
}

function LoadInBingoBalls(){

var first = 0;
var last = 78;
var random;

 var bag = [];

//Heres the part i get confused!
for (var i = first; i <= last; i++) {

do
         bag.push(i) = setSquare(i);

    while(bag.indexOf(i) !== -1)             
  }

 return bag;
 }
 }
```

Comment: You have to create an array with all numbers from 1 to 78, then pop one by one  randomly until you qet all balls.

Comment: "Someone please help." isn't a question. Please review [ask].

Comment: Does OP want numbers from 1 to 78 randomized, or 78 random numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating random numbers with no duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040001/creating-random-numbers-with-no-duplicates)

Comment: 24 random numbers between values 0 - 78...

Answer (score 2):

This function will create the array and check to see if it contains the number before pushing:

working example: https://jsbin.com/cabofa/1/edit?js,console

```
function randNum (max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
}

function makeArray(n) {
  var arr = [];
  while (arr.length < n) {
    var random = randNum(n);
    if (arr.indexOf(random) === -1) {
      arr.push(random);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: if (arr.indexOf(random) === -1) {  what does the -1 mean here...

Comment: indexOf returns the index of the number or -1:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: is there any way to do this with a for loop instead of while loop?

Comment: No... You don't know how many times to loop

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with all the possible values:

```
var possibles = [];

for(i=1; i<=78; i++) {
    possibles.push(i);
}
```

Shuffle that array of values to be random:

```
function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length; i; i -= 1) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        x = a[i - 1];
        a[i - 1] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }

    return a;
}

var shuffled = shuffle(possibles);
```

Now pop a value from your new array to get a random element from it:

```
var popped = shuffled.pop();
console.log(popped);
```

You can call pop() as many times as you want until the array is empty, which will return undefined. For example:

```
for(i=0; i<shuffled.length; i++) {
    console.log(shuffled.pop());
}
```

Comment: I can't see here where you have checked for duplicates...

Comment: No need to check for duplicates. pop() will remove the last element from the array which has already been shuffled. I have edited my answer and added a final example. Run that in a console and you will get random elements from 1 to 78 without duplicates.