# Java Randomly Select 10 rows from 100 rows in CSV

Tags: java, random

I am working on a Java program and I have a data.csv file with 100 rows. I want to randomly select 10 rows. The Data looks like this:

```
    T1  T2  T3  T4  T5
    1   1.0  1   0   1
    1   1.0  0   0   1
    0   0.0  1   1   0
```

I have managed to read in the CSV file using the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try
    {
        Scanner readIn = new Scanner (new File ("data.csv") );
        while ( readIn.hasNext() )
        {               
            line = readIn.nextLine();
            str = line.split(",",-1);        
        }
        readIn.close();     
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ob)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found..." );
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you considered adding all the rows to an ArrayList then removing 10 rows at random? maybe not the most efficient way but it's possibly the easiest to code.

Comment: what collections are you using for the data? or are you using a normal array?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: P.S. why is this tagged "opencsv" if you are not using that library?

Comment: @tnw his question is to provide him some algorithm to randomly pick 10 rows from possible 100 rows.

Comment: @OusmaneDiaw That's a code request, not a question. I'd like to know OP's specific problem **and question**.

Comment: A good starting point would be to actually save the data you are reading in instead of just reading in a line and then overriding it in with the next iteration.

Comment: @tnw you're correct.

Comment: I have created an ArrayList of strings and I have added each item to the list. I also have SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
   int row = random.nextInt(list.size()); System.out.println(list.get(row));  This gives me only one item selected at random, but I need 10 random items out of 100. I can code if given an algorithm to start with...please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated code with duplicate number check:

```
    int j=0;
    Map<Integer,Integer> numberMap=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(); 
    while(j!=10)
    {
        int row = random.nextInt(list.size()); 
        if(!numberMap.containsKey(Integer.valueOf(row)))
        {
            numberMap.put(Integer.valueOf(row), Integer.valueOf(row));
            System.out.println("Row "+row+"="+list.get(row));
            j++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is obviously not the perfect solution as there is a slight chance that the random value could generate the same row more than once.

Comment: Yes, in that case  we need to store previous number something say map and check for if exist condition.

Comment: ***DON'T*** create a new `SecureRandom()` on each iteration of the loop!!!

Comment: This works if the sample size is a small proportion of the data.  For larger proportions, it's faster and easier to use `Collections.shuffle()` and iterate through the shuffled result.

Comment: This user has smaller data set for larger data set he has to follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040001/creating-random-numbers-with-no-duplicates