# All unique paths in a directed acyclic graph, in randomized order, via Python generator?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, generator, graph-algorithm

I have a [Directed Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (DAG), which consists of layers, with two subsequent layers being completely bipartite (much like a neural net), like the following:

[image: A DAG with 8 vertices]

I want to **stream** all paths in the DAG, in an **iterative manner**, via some **generator**, in a randomized order. Because, **output must not be in order**, textbook DFS approaches are out of question. Memory is an issue, so I don't want to store any paths that I have yielded before, except the DAG alone, which could be modified however is needed.

Example, the desired output for the above DAG is:

```
(1, 4, 6, 8)
(3, 4, 5, 8)
(2, 4, 7, 8)
(3, 4, 6, 8)
(1, 4, 5, 8)
(3, 4, 7, 8)
(1, 4, 7, 8)
(2, 4, 6, 8)
(2, 4, 5, 8)
```

instead of the following produced by DFS:

```
(1, 4, 5, 8)
(1, 4, 6, 8)
(1, 4, 7, 8)
(2, 4, 5, 8)
(2, 4, 6, 8)
(2, 4, 7, 8)
(3, 4, 5, 8)
(3, 4, 6, 8)
(3, 4, 7, 8)
```

Thanks for your help.

Update:

I have the following code

```
graph = {
    1: set([4]),
    2: set([4]),
    3: set([4]),
    4: set([5, 6, 7]),
    5: set([8]),
    6: set([8]),
    7: set([8])
}

def dfs_paths(graph, start, goal):
    stack = [(start, [start])]
    while stack:
        (vertex, path) = stack.pop()
        for next in graph[vertex] - set(path):
            if next == goal:
                yield path + [next]
            else:
                stack.append((next, path + [next]))

def run_paths():
    for start in [1, 2, 3]:
        for path in dfs_paths(graph, start, 8):
            print path
```

Finding all paths and then randomly streaming them will not work for me, as I do not want to store any paths I will be generating.

Comment: you can shuffle the edges before calling dfs whenever you reach a node

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: So you want to randomize the ouput. Can't you use the `random` module?

Comment: @marvel308 Shufle the edges, and still do DFS? Things would still in order no? Could you flesh out your comment as an answer?

Comment: @ScottHunter, I can show you my DFS code, but that's all I have.

Comment: @Ain Then please show that. It's better to show a flawed attempt than no code at all.

Comment: you can find all paths and randomize the output, or wouldn't that work for you ?

Comment: @ScottHunter Christian Dean, I have attached my code to the post. marvel308, I cannot store any paths I will be generating. I want to stream all paths in randomized order.

Comment: Do we have any constraints on the structure of this graph, beyond being directed and acyclic? Particularly, is the underlying problem the same as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497405/stream-all-unordered-shuffled-unique-permutation-of-elements-in-a-nested-list-l), implying that the graph can be separated into layers with nodes in each layer only connecting to the next layer, and with each pair of consecutive layers forming a complete bipartite graph?

Comment: @user2357112, absolutely! This is another formulation of my previous question. All your assumptions are correct.

Comment: @Ain: Please edit those requirements into this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that you're contradicting yourself: you want output to be "strictly unordered", but you have no state or memory for the sequence.  This is simply not possible via information theory.  However, if your goal is simply to have a "shuffle" -- a different sequence that a casual observer won't recognize as a predetermined sequence, then you have a chance.

First, determine your choice points and sizes.  For instance, your choices above are [1, 2, 3] x [5, 6, 7].  This gives you 3*3 = 9 paths to generate.  Let's add a third choice for illustration, a [T, F] on the end.  This gives 3*3*2 = 18 paths.

Now, use your favorite "perfect sequence generator" to create a simple function for you.  I'm assuming that *something* int he RNG process is allowed to recall the previous value or seed.  For ridiculous simplicity, let's use a trivial linear sequence `f(n) = f(n-1) + 5 (mod 18)`.  This will give the sequence `0 5 10 15 2 7 12 17 ...`

Now have your path generator call this function on each iteration.  Simply convert the returned "random" number to digits in the given base sequence -- 3|3|2 in this case.  Let's look at the value 7, taking the conversion from left to right, using the bases in order:

```
7 divmod 3 => mod 1, quotient 2
2 divmod 3 => mod 2, quotient 0
0 divmod 2 => mod 0
```

Thus, you choose the path with elements 1, 2, 0 of your three choice arrays.  The resulting path is (chosen nodes in **bold**):

**2** 4 **6** 8 **T**

Is that clear?  Does it solve your problem?

Comment: this is no better than randomly choosing a vertex at any given layer, which is my current go to strategy.

Comment: But, I guess you're right. Without really storing previous paths, there is no way to enumerate all paths randomly.

Comment: @Ain exactly the problem of information theory: if you have no way to store information that will tell you whether you've already randomly chosen this solution, then you're stuck.  The best I can suggest is this answer, where the RNGs inherent status (the most recent seed value) embodies a position within a psuedo-random sequence -- a sequence that will exhaust all combinations before repeating.  You decode that single integer to get the particular combination.