# Android Studio - Random Number within range and no duplicates

Tags: android, random

I was working on a quiz app in Android studio..

- I have 2 tables which are the solutions and questions..
- In my game, I wanna create a random number in the range of this table without duplicates..
- with this random number I update my questions and answers..

I try this code now to create numbers (with duplicates):

```
Random rand = new Random();

n = rand.nextInt(QuestionLibrary.mChoices.length) + 1;
```

here is the photo of my game

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have much numbers, you can make a collection with all of them, shuffle and then take one by one from it.
If you have a lot of numbers, then better aproach would be to make an empty collection and add every number that random function returns if it already does not exists. If number already exists, get another one, and so on.

Please read more here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4040014/7270175

EDIT: added code snippet that reproduces MAX number of different random numbers without duplicates.

```
private static int MAX = 1000;
private static boolean[] numbers;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random generator = new Random();
    numbers = new boolean[MAX + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        System.out.println(getRandomWithoutDuplicates(generator));
    }
}

private static int getRandomWithoutDuplicates(Random generator) {
    int randomNum;
    do {
        randomNum = generator.nextInt(MAX);
    } while (numbers[randomNum]);
    numbers[randomNum] = true;
    return randomNum;
}
```

Comment: i already have try this in your post and dont work in my case.. anything else? :/

Comment: Can you explain what  is exactly a problem with solution?

Comment: see bellow.. with this code i update my questions from table but with this n i take dublicates.. i need to take only once this question..

Comment: So what does getChoice(1,2,3,4) method?

Comment: i use this code at my top of my programm? and what variable i use on my update questions? randomnum?