# Printing an array of random words given the number of words requesed by input in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, input

```
        String sql_query = "SELECT * FROM words";
        ResultSet rs = statement_object.executeQuery(sql_query);
        List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();
        int size = wordsList.size();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of words you want to sort");
        int numWords = input.nextInt();
        int j4 = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            String words = rs.getString("Word");
            words = words.toLowerCase();
            dictionaryWords.add(words);
            j4++;
            
            for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++) {
                String [] randomWords = new String[numWords];
                Random rand = new Random();
                System.out.println(words);
            }
            }
```

The code prints the words in my database repetitively.
For example,

Enter the number of words you want to sort: 3

Ape

Ape

Ape

Rose

Rose

Rose

Bite

Bite

Bite

I need it to print to pull 3 random words from the database (or whatever given input) and print that result. For example,
Enter the number of words you want to sort: 3

Ape

Rose

Bite

Comment: I'd break this down: **a.** Do the query (if there's only one column required, don't `SELECT *`, just the necessary column). **b.** Add the words to your `List`. **c.** Call `Collections.shuffle` on the `List` and remove the first n words. Take a copy first if you like

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions here:

1. why is my code printing each word three times, and
2. how do I print three random words from the database?

##### Q1

To answer the first question, please read what your code is doing carefully:

- the while loop iterates over each row in the database:

  - `while (rs.next())`
- the for loop iterates the number of times you input into `numWords`:

  - `for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++)`
- the println prints the word it just read from the database:

  - `String words = rs.getString("Word");`
  - `System.out.println(words);`

So, if you think about it, it's saying "for each word in the database, loop three times and print that word". Which is exactly what you've observed.

##### Q2

To answer the second questions,

1. I would first get all words from the database and put that into an array. That's what you've done with `dictionaryWords`:

   - `dictionaryWords.add(words);`
2. Then I would loop `numWords` time. So pull the `for` loop outside of the `while` loop.
3. Then on each iteration of the loop, get a random word from `dictionaryWords`.  Your code is not actually using the `rand` object you created. Take a look at this Stackoverflow question for examples on how to use it:

   - [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Comment: Take a look at [Creating random numbers _with no duplicates_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040001/creating-random-numbers-with-no-duplicates). But shuffling a list (as per go00se's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68764866/printing-an-array-of-random-words-given-the-number-of-words-requesed-by-input-in#comment121527407_68764866) in the question) is probably the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it better to get the exact result from the database:

```
//add order by if want the result to be shuffle
//MSQL
select top 3 distinct(word) from words ORDER BY NEWID()

//mysql
select distinct(word) from words ORDER BY RAND() limit 3 
...etc (see exact syntax for your rdbms)
```

Note: Order by can have a second parameter to refine sort but in case on first criteria random will not work.

Doing additional java-processing is time consuming. Besides that, if you all records and columns you will increase query execution time.

If really want to retrieve all words then you could use a `Set` to store only distinct words, but still need to transfer to a `List` in order to shuffle and after sort. Here it's now up to you how it's better to procced.

Still there is a work around using subquery.

```
//mysql
select w.word
from
    (
      select distinct(word) word 
      from words 
      order by rand() 
      limit 3
    ) w
order by w.word desc //asc default
```

Or just sort it from java having still an enhancement, maybe using a `TreeSet` which retain elements sorted, etc.

Comment: You cannot shuffle a `Set`, you need a `List` for that.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, yes my mistake