# How to get Random Number

Tags: c#, .net, random

I want to get 20 random numbers between 1 to 100, but the number should not repeated....

**Updated:** 
If I have 20 names in which any 5 to be selected at random one by one but the name came once not to be called again.....

Comment: That's not random. Random sequences _do_ have repeated numbers. Can you clarify?

Comment: It's not random, but it is still useful for some things (for example, randomly playing the songs on an album without any repeats).

Comment: You want a random shuffle, google fisher-yates.

Comment: Maybe better to call it "mostly random"

Comment: Here you go: 4,19,50,3,10,99,7,12,71,28,17,49,83,75,44,37,96,30,15,42

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked this a year or so ago.

[Unique Random Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-random-numbers-in-o1)

The selected answer is brilliant, I thought.

Answer (score 7):

Put the numbers in a list, and pick from the list:

```
List<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList();

Random rnd = new Random();
List<int> picks = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(n => {
  int index = rnd.Next(numbers.Count);
  int pick = numbers[index];
  numbers.RemoveAt(index);
  return pick;
});
```

This is probably the simplest way to solve it, but it's not the most efficient. Removing items in a list involves moving the following items. With a bit more code you could avoid that move, but for most purposes the code is good enough as it is.