# list of unique random numbers in an Interval in Ada

Tags: algorithm, random, ada

I'm sorry to bother you I know [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-random-numbers-in-o1) have been asked quite a lot but never with Ada... I was wondering if there were in the Ada standard library a way to generate a list of unique random numbers (you never pick twice the same number) in O(n) 
In a way is there an implementation of the Knuth-Fisher-Yates algorithm in Ada?

Comment: I'm not aware of any library that already has this, but that K-F-Y algorithm looks pretty straightforward to implement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a discussion of implementing the [`Fisher–Yates`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ada/browse_frm/thread/a10fc2d4d530dd05). Basically, you need a different range of [`Discrete_Random`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-5-2.html) in each iteration, as shown [here](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#Ada); [`Float_Random`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-5-2.html) is an alternative, as mentioned in [A.5.2(50), Note 16](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-5-2.html). If bias isn't critical, this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/war) may be sufficient.

In any case, *shuffling* is *O(n)*, but *selecting* can be *O(1)*.

Addendum: The complexity of *creating* the set depends on the [implementation](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-18-7.html). For example, [Containers.Hashed_Sets, A.18.8(88/2)](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-18-8.html) and [Containers.Ordered_Sets, A.18.9(116/2)](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-18-9.html).

Comment: Isnt Dealing/Generating the numbers O(n) also ? after all one needs to check if the number is unique ? (repeated linear search on an array)

Comment: @NWS: Good point. I used the word _dealing_ carelessly; I meant _selecting_. IIUC, uniqueness is coincident with _creating_ the initial set, with complexity depending on the implementation.

Comment: getting back to the Question, if we generate and put in a sorted list, _Before_ we shuffle the numbers might reduce a little :).

Comment: @NWS: Fisher–Yates only permutes an existing set. The complexity of creating the set depends on the [implementation](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-18-7.html).

Answer (score 2):

Given that you want:
a) Random numbers from 0 to 1000
and
b) the numbers are not to repeat
according to the link you provided, you could do this rather easily.

Just fill an array with the range of values and perform some number of swaps on randomly chosen elements thereof; this guarantees both requirements are upheld.

Comment: +1 This is the straightforward approach, but the selection of "some number of swaps" can be a source of bias.

Comment: This is true. However you may be able to reduce that a bit by using a RNG with a cycle/range equal to your Array's range (perhaps using MOD) and swapping that index with the 'current' element for all elements.

Then the main thing that the bias would come from would be the RNG itself.

Comment: In the [example cited](http://home.roadrunner.com/~jbmatthews/war.html) the [bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Implementation_errors) hinges on "selecting `j` from the entire range of valid array indexes on every iteration." Sadly, it's over and above any bias from the PRNG.

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty of coding it up.
You'll need to With Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random.

```
   Generic
      Low, High : Integer;
   Package Initialization is
      SubType Element is Integer Range Low..High;
      Function Incrementor Return Element;
      Type Element_Array is Array(Element) of Element;

      Values : Element_Array;
      Procedure Print;
   End Initialization;

   Package Body Initialization is
      Count : Element := Element'Last;

      Function Incrementor Return Element is
      begin
         Return Result : Element:= Count do
            Null;
            Count:= Element'Pred( Result );
         Exception
               When Constraint_Error => Count:= Element'Last;
         End Return;
      end Incrementor;

      Procedure Swap( Index_1, Index_2 : In Integer ) is
         Temp : Constant Element:= Values( Integer(Index_1) );
      begin
         Values( Integer(Index_1) ):= Values( Integer(Index_2) );
         Values( Integer(Index_2) ):= Temp;
      end Swap;

      Procedure Print is
      begin
         Put_Line( "Length: " & Values'Length'Img );
         Put( "(" );
         For Index in Values'First..Integer'Pred(Values'Last) loop
            Put( Values(Index)'Img & ',' );
         end loop;
         Put( Values(Values'Last)'Img );
         Put_Line( ")" );
      end Print;


   Begin
      Shuffle:
      Declare
         Package Random_Element is New
        Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random( Element );
         Number : Random_Element.Generator;
         Use Random_Element;
      Begin
         Values:= Element_Array'( Others => Incrementor );
         Reset( Number );
         For Index in Element'Range loop
            Swap( Integer(Index), Integer(Random(Number)) );
         end loop;
      End Shuffle;
   End Initialization;
```

And you can test it out with something like:

```
   Test:
   Declare
      Package Q is new 
    Initialization( Low => 0, High => 1000 );
   Begin
      Q.Print;
   End Test;
```

Comment: Becasue it selects from "the entire range of valid array indexes on every iteration," I'm afraid this has the the same [bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Implementation_errors).

Comment: But selecting an invalid index would be, in a word, erroneous.

Comment: The selection isn't out of range; it just makes some shuffles more likely than others. You have to select from the _remaining_ elements in each iteration. This [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Implementation_errors) finally helped me see how.