# Generate a table with random elements

Tags: random, ada, tabular

I am new with Ada programming. I am trying to generate a 80 column and 40 rows table, each case is randomly filled with either M or V. Any help with how to create this kind of table would be much appreciated !

Here's what I have so far for the table in .ads :

```
     package Life is
type Grid is (mort, vivant);
     type TableauCell is array ( 0..80, 0..40 ) of Grid;
procedure Grid_Random_Fill(A : in out Grid);
end Life;
```

and the randomization:

```
    with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO, Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random ;
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

package body Life is

procedure Grid_Random_Fill is
         type  Life is (V, M);

   package Random_Life is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random (Life) ;
   use Random_Life ;
   G : Generator ;
 begin
   Reset (G) ; -- intialise the generator
   loop
 Case Random(G) is
 when V => 
      put("V"); -- put V in table
 when M =>
    put("M"); -- put M in table
   end case;  
    end loop ;
end Grid_Random_Fill;
       end life;
```

Unfortunately I can't get it to compile - and I don't see how I can automatically generate M and V into my table. I'm not sure I was clear, I'm all new to coding.

Comment: A related example is cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5369385/230513).

Comment: "I can't get it to compile" is often something rather simple. Its good form here to give us your compiler error, rather than force someone who wants to answer you to run this through a compiler themselves, or try to play "human compiler".

Comment: Why have you called the enumeration in the spec Grid - the name clearly implies an array? Type TableauCell is 81x41, not 80x40. Why does Grid_Random_Fill (the version in the spec) take a parameter of type Grid - you surely mean TableauCell?  (Perhaps you were originally thinking of the two types the other way round, ie TableauCell would be the enumeration.) Don't you think that the Grid_Random_Fill in the body should match the one in the spec? Why do you declare a type Life inside Grid_Random_Fill - you surely mean to use the Grid declared in the spec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this has the feel of homework, how about an overly-complex, overly-generalized example?
Everything works, except the randomization, which is an exercise left to the reader.

`Test_Table.adb`

```
With
Tabling,
Ada.Streams.Stream_IO,
Ada.Text_IO.Text_Streams;

Use
Ada.Text_IO;

Procedure Test_Table is
    -- Here we declare a stream and associate it with the standard-output, 
    -- this can easily be altered to any file. Yay streams!
    Output : Access Ada.Streams.Root_Stream_Type:= 
        Ada.Text_IO.Text_Streams.Stream( Standard_Output );

    Package test is new Tabling( Rows => 40, Cols => 80 );

    temp : test.Table;

Begin
    -- A single line to write the table.
    Test.Table'Write( Output, temp );
    New_Line;
End Test_Tables;
```

Now isn't that nice and simple? Well, here's the over-complex & over-generalized part: the specification and implementation!

`Tabling.ads`

```
Pragma Ada_2012;
With Ada.Streams;
Generic
 Rows : Positive := 3;
 Cols : Positive := 4;
Package Tabling is 
-- Tables with rows or columns exceeding 200 are absurd, so we disallow them.
Maximum : constant:= 200;
Pragma Assert (Rows <= Maximum and Cols <= Maximum);

-- Table is a private entity.
Type Table is private;

-- Forward declaring the rows and columns here.
Type Col is private;
Type Row is private;
Private
Use Ada.Streams;

-- We are defining a type with elements of 'V' or 'M'.
Type Element_Type is ( 'M', 'V' );
-- We are declaring a stream writing function.
Procedure Write(
    Stream  : access Root_Stream_Type'Class;
        Item    : in Element_Type);
-- We are overriding the default write function with the one we defined.
For Element_Type'Write use Write;

-- Because we don't want an allocation wrror we restrict index-ranges to
-- a more reasonable value.
SubType Short_Positive is Positive Range Positive'First..Maximum;

-- We create subtypes representing the ranges that Rows or Columns take.
subtype column_index is Short_Positive Range Positive'First..Cols;
subtype row_index    is Short_Positive Range Positive'First..Rows;

-- Here we define stream-writing functions for rows and columns.
Procedure Write(
    Stream  : access Root_Stream_Type'Class;
    Item    : in Col);
Procedure Write(
    Stream  : access Root_Stream_Type'Class;
    Item    : in Row);
-- Here we override the stream-writing methods for rows and columns.
For Col'Write Use Write;
For Row'Write Use Write;

-- Here we finally define Rows and Columns.
Type Col is Array(column_index)of Element_Type;
Type Row is Array( row_index ) of Col;

-- THIS IS A STUB, SUBSTITUTED FOR YOUR CALL TO RANDOM.
Function RANDOM_CALL Return Element_Type is ( 'M' );

-- Finally we define the stream-writing for a table...
Procedure Write(
    Stream  : access Root_Stream_Type'Class;
    Item    : in Table);

-- and define what a table is...
Type Table is record
Data : Row:= ( others => (others => RANDOM_CALL) );
end record;
-- finishing off by assigning our write function to the type.
For Table'Write Use Write;  

End Tabling;
```

`Tabling.adb`

```
package body Tabling is
-- Quick definition of the new-line, windows-style.
New_Line : Constant String:= ASCII.CR & ASCII.LF;

-- Implementations of our stream writing functions.
Procedure Write(
    Stream  : access Root_Stream_Type'Class;
    Item    : in Element_Type) is
-- Convert takes the element-type and transforms it into a character.
Function Convert (Input : Element_Type:= Item) Return Character is
begin
    -- A simple mapping using case, it also has the advantage of raising
    -- a compiler error should the valuse "Element_Type" can take change.
    case Input is
    when 'M' => return 'm';
    when 'V' => return 'v';
    end case;
end Convert;
begin
Character'Write( Stream, Convert );
end Write;


Procedure Write(
    Stream  : access Root_Stream_Type'Class;
    Item    : in Col) is
begin
-- Using the new-style for-loop, we iterate over the given columns,
-- taking care to wrap the elements in the table's cell-definition tag.
for Element of Item loop
    String'Write( Stream, ASCII.HT & "<td>" );
    Element_Type'Write( Stream, Element );
    String'Write( Stream, "</td>" & New_Line );
end loop;
end Write;


Procedure Write(
    Stream  : access Root_Stream_Type'Class;
    Item    : in Row) is
begin
-- Using the new-style loop, we iterate through the row, wrapping each
-- in the table-row tag, <tr>.
for Element of Item loop
    String'Write( Stream, "<tr>" & New_Line);
    col'Write( Stream, Element );
    String'Write( Stream, "</tr>" & New_Line);
end loop;
end Write;


Procedure Write(
    Stream  : access Root_Stream_Type'Class;
    Item    : in Table) is
begin
-- Start the table.
String'Write(Stream, "<Table>" & New_Line);
-- Write out the rows.
Row'Write   (Stream, Item.Data );
-- End the table.
String'Write(Stream, "</Table>");
end Write;

End Tabling;
```

Comment: Good Lord! What is this, comp.lang.ada?  :-)

Comment: LOL - No, but I have been hanging out there. // I did warn that it was over-complicated & over-generalized.

Comment: COuld you please have a look at my post, i've edited it and put a bit more infos - still a bit lost though..

Comment: Two items: 1 -- your subprogram needs to match so change the body's to `procedure Grid_Random_Fill (A : in out Grid)` and 2 -- you have an infinite loop, and aren't touching the grid parameter.

Comment: You seem to have gone to a lot of trouble to write this person's code for him (I assume 'him'), which I don't think is going to help him understand what's wrong with the code in his question.

Comment: I got bored, needed something to do.

Comment: @MarcC - If I wanted to work on an API I'd put a little more into this: https://github.com/OneWingedShark/TAO-GL (I need to get it from OpenGL 1.1 to 4.3 & do a little restructuring.)

Answer (score 4):

This sounds homeworkish, so this is going to be kept somewhat abstract.

Declare a two-element type to represent M and V.

Declare an 80x40 array of that type.

Instantiate [Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-5-2.html#I6105) with that type.

Iterate over the array bounds, setting each array element via a call to the random number package's Random() function.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your response. Here's what I have so far:

Answer (score 2):

The procedure body for Grid_Random_Fill needs to agree with the specification, which is:

```
procedure Grid_Random_Fill(A : in out Grid);
```

The body does not include the parameter A.

Comment: +1, but I highly suspect the compiler was trying to tell the OQ the same.

Comment: I think you're right.  I just figured user may not have understood the message, since the error was not corrected in the original.

Comment: Clearly. Which is what I tried to point out in the comment to the question. He could have saved everyone a lot of typing by just putting in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The solution will involve two nested loops, over the range of the two dimensions in the array you declared.

Answer (score 1):

And the simple answer :

```
with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random;
with Ada.Text_Io;

procedure Main is

   type Cell_T is (M,V);
   type Rows_T is new Integer Range 1 .. 40;
   type Cols_T is new Integer Range 1 .. 80;
   type Grid_T is array (Rows_T,Cols_T) of Cell_T;
   package Rand is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random (Cell_T);

   G : Rand.Generator;
   Grid : constant Grid_T := (others => (others => Rand.Random(G)));

begin

   for R in Rows_T'range loop
      for C in Cols_T'range loop
         Ada.Text_Io.Put (Cell_T'Image (Grid (R,C)));
      end loop;
      Ada.Text_Io.New_Line;
   end loop;

end Main;
```

Output :

```
$ ./main
VMMVVMMMVMMMVVVMMMVVVMMVVVMVVVVMMMMVMMMMVVMVMVVMMVMMMVVMMMMVMMVMMVMMMMVMMVVMVVMM
VVVMVVVVMMMMMMVVMVMMVMMMVMMMVVMVVVVVMVVVMVMVVVMVMVVVMVMMMVMVVVMVMMVVVMVVMVVVVVMM
VVMVVVVVVVMVVVVMVVVMVVMMVMVVVMVMMMVMMMVVVMMMVVVMMMMMVVVVMVMVVVVVVVMMVVMVMVMMVVVM
VMMVVMVMVVMVMVVMMVMMVMVVMVMVMMVVMMVVMMVMVVVVVVMVMVMMMMMMVMVVVMMVMMMMVMVVVVMVMVVM
VVVVMMMMMVVMMMMVVMMMVMMMVVMVVVMMMMMMVMVMMVMMVVVMMVMMMMVVMVMVMMMMVMMMVMVVVVMMMVMM
VMMVVMMMMMVVMMMVVVVMMVMMVVVVVVVVVVMVMVMVVVVVVVVMVMVMVVMVMMMMMVMMVVVVVVVVMVVVVVVV
VVMMMMVVVMMVMVMVMVVMMMMMVMVVVVMMVVMVVVMMMMMMMMMMMMMVMMVVMVVMVMMVMMMVVVMMMVVVMVVV
MVMVMMVMVVVMVVVVVVVMMMMVVVMMVVVMVMMVVMVVVMVMVMMMMVVVVMVVMMVMVMVVVMVMMVMMMVVMVVVV
MMVMMVMMMVVVVMVVVVVVVMVVVVMMMVMMMVMVMMMVMVVVMVMMVMVMVMVVMMMVVVVVMVVMVMVMVVMMMVVV
VVMMMMMMMVMVVMVMVVVMVVMVMMMMMVVVVVVVMVMMVVMMMMVVVMVVMVVMVVVVMMVVVVMMMMVMMVMMMMMM
VVVMMMMVMMVVVVVMVVMVVMVMMMMMMVMMMMVVMVVVMVMVVMMVVMMMVVMMMVMVVVVVMMVVVMVVVMMVVMMM
VMVVMMVMVVVMMMVVVVMMMMVVVMVVVVMMMVMVVVVMMMVVVMVVMMVVVMVMMMVMMVVVMVMMMMMMVMVVVMVV
VMVMMMVMMMVMMMMMMVMMMVVMMMMVMMMVVMMVMMMVVMVVVMMMMVMVMVMVVMMVMMMVVMVVMVMMMMVMVMMM
VMVVVMMMMMVMMMMVVVVMMMVVMMVVMVVMVMVVMVVVVMVMMVMMVMMVMVVMVVVVVVMMMMVMVMMMVVVMMVVV
VVMVVMVMVVVMMMMMVVVMVMVVMVMVMMVVVMVVMMVMMVMMVVMVMMMMVMVVMMMVVMVMMMMMMMMVMVMMVVVM
MVVVVVMMVVMMMVMVMVMVMVVMMMVVMMVMVMVVVMVVVVVMMMMVVVMVVMVVMVVVVVVVVMMVMMVVVVVVVVMV
MVMMMMVMMVVVVVMMMVMVVVMVVMVVMVVVVMVVVMVVMVVMMVVVMVMVVMMMVVMMMMVVMMMVMVMMMMVMMMVV
MVVMVMVVMMVMVMMVMVVVMVVVVVVVVVVVVMVMMVVMMVMMMVVVMMVMMMMVVMVMVMVMVMVVVMMMMVMVVVMM
MMVVVVVMVVMVMMVMMVVVVVMVMMMMMVVVVMVMVMMVVVMMMVMVVVMVMMMMVVMMVMVMVVVVMMMVMMMMVVMV
MMMVVMMMVMVVVVVMVMVMMVVVMVVMMVMVVMVVMVMMVMVVVVVVVMMMVVVMVVVVMVVVVVVMMMVVMMMMMMMV
VVMMVMMVMMMMVMVVVMMMMVVMVMVVMVVVMMMVMVMMMMMVMMVVMMMMVMVVMMMVMVMMMMVMMMMVVVMMMVMM
VMVVVMMVVVVVVMVMMMVVVMVMMVVMVVMVVVVVVVVMMMMMVVVMMMMVMVVVMVMVMMVVVMMVMMVMVMMVVVVV
MMVMMMVMVMVMMVVMMMMVMMVMVMMVVMMMVVVMVVVVVVVVMMMVMVVVMMMVMMVMMVMVMVMMMVVMMMMMVMMM
MMVVMMMMMVVMMMMVMVVMVVMVVVVVMVVVMVMMVMMVVMMMVVVMVVVVMVVMMVVMVVMMMVMVMVMVMVMMMMVM
MVMVVVVMMMVVMVVMMVMVVMVMVVVMMVMVMMMVMVMMMMMVMVMVVMMVMMMVMVMVVMMVMMMVVMVVVVVMVMVV
VMVVMMMVMVMMMMMMMMVVVMVMVVVVMVVVVVMVMVVMVMVVVVVMMVVVVVVMMMMMVVMVMVVVVMVMMMMVVVVM
MVMVMVMMMMVMMVVVMMMMMVMMVVMMMMVVVVVVVMMVVVVMMMMMVVMMVVMVVVVVMMMVVVVMVMVVVMMVMMVM
VVVVVMMMMVVMMMMVVMVVVMMVMMVMVVVVVMVVVVVMVMVVMMVVVMVVMMMVMVVVVMMMVVVMVVMVMVMMMMVV
MVVVMVMVMVMMMMMVMVMMVMMVVMVVVVMMVMVVMVVVMVMVMVMMVVVVMMVVMMMVVVMMMMMVVMMMMMVMVVVV
MVMVMMMVVVMVVVVVVMMVMVVVMMVMVMMVMMVMVVVMMMMVMMVMMVMMMMMMVMVVVMVMMVMVMMMVVMMMMVMV
VVMVVMVVMVMVMMMMVMVVVMMMMMVMMMMMMMVVVVVMMMVVVMVMMMMVVVMVMVMVVMMMVMMMMVMMMVMMMVMV
MMMMVMMVVVVMVVMMVMVVMVVVMVMMVVVMVVVMMVVVVVMMMVMVVVMMMMVVMVMMVMVMVMVMMMVMMVVVMMMM
VMMMMVVMMVMVMVVVVVMVVVMVMMMVVMMMVVMVVVMMMMVVVVMVMMVVMMVVVVMMMVMVMVVMVMMVMVMMMMMV
MMMMVMMMMMVMMVMMMVMVVMMVVVMVMMVVMVMVVMVVMMMMMVMVVVMVVMMVVVVMMMMMMMMVMVVVMVVMVMVV
VMMVMMMMMVMVMMMVVVVVMVMVMVMMVMVMVVVVVVVMMMMVVMMVVVMVVVMMMVVVMMVMMVVVMVVVMVMMMVMM
VMVMMVVVMVMMMMVVVMMVMMMVVVVMVMVVVMMVMMVMMVVVMMMMMVVVMVMMMMVVMVVVMVVMMMVMMMVMVVVM
VVVMMMVVMMMMMVMVVVMVVMVVVVVVMMMVVMVVMVVMVMVMVVVMVMMMMVMMMMMVMMMMVVMVVVVVVMVMMVMV
VVVVMVVVMVMMMMMMVVMVVVVVVMMMMMMVVMMMMVMMVMMVMMMVMVVMMMMMVMMMMMMMMVVVMMMMVVMVMVVM
MMVVVMVMVVMVVMVVVMMVVMVMVMMVMMMVMVMMMMMVVVMMMMVMMVMVVVVMVMMMMVVVMMMVVVMMMVMMMMMM
VMMVMMMVMVVMMVVVVMMVMMVVMVMVMMVMMMVMMVVMVVVVMVMVVVVMMMMMMMVVVMVMVMMVVVVMVMVMMMVV
```