# Generate random but non-repeating numbers (C++)

Tags: c++, random

I want to generate a set of non-repeating random numbers from `0...n`.

> e.g: [9,2,5,7,4,6,1,3,8,0]

My current method is generating random numbers in a while loop until the `std::set` count is `n`. Obviously this takes quite a while to finish for large sets. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It looks to me like you want to shuffle a sequence `[1,n]` :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926433/how-to-shuffle-a-stdvector-in-c

Comment: @cnicutar: sunofa... now I feel silly... you are absolutely right! :) if you put that as the answer, I will checkmark it!

Comment: It's OK. Why don't you answer your own question with a nice C++ idiomatic example of doing this ?

Comment: If the number of numbers and the range of the numbers isn't identical, see [Floyd's sampling algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2394292/179910).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-repeating random number generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382037/non-repeating-random-number-generator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the sequential values in a STL collection, and then use [random_shuffle](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/) to shuffle them appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Shuffle and iterate your list of numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v;


    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        v.push_back(i);

    random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());

    for(vector<int>::iterator itr=v.begin(); itr != v.end(); ++itr)
        cout << *itr << endl;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

generating a sequence and shuffling may be what you want, however its not necessarily the same as generating random numbers and discarding ones that have occurred before. For example, if you want 10 unique random numbers from between 1 and 2 million you obviously won't get the desired distribution by just generating

```
1,000,000
1,000,001
1,000,002
1,000,003
1,000,004
1,000,005
1,000,006
1,000,007
1,000,008
1,000,009
```

and shuffling those.

You could instead generate random numbers from the desired range until you have the number desired, then sort and unique the results, and then generate enough additional random number to make up whatever was eliminated by the uniquing (ensuring the new numbers are unique as you go). If the range of generated numbers isn't that much larger than the number of values you want then you might just generate some extra values to start off with. In any case the final step once you have the desired number of unique values, is to shuffle them so they are not in sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
void main()
{


    int *tab;
    int nr;
    srand(time(0));

    cout << "How many numbers do you want to generate?:  ";
    cin >> nr;

    tab = new int[nr]; //Dynamic memory allocation


    for (int i = 0;i < nr;i++)
        tab[i] = i+1;
    random_shuffle(&tab[0], &tab[nr]); //Shuffle the numbers from tab;

    cout << "\t\tMixed numbers are: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0;i < nr;i++)
        cout << "Number [" << i + 1 << "]: " << tab[i]<<endl;



    delete [] tab;
    cin.get();
```