# About a non-repeat rand function

Tags: c++, arrays, random, repeat

I tried to generate 25 arrays, each of them should contains number 1 to 25 without repetition and out of order. I executed the code to generate an array, there was no repetition. There were repeating numbers in the array when I tried to map the array into the 2D array.

Here is my code

```
int permutation(int arraystore[]){

int item[25], index;
for (int x = 0; x < 25; x++)
    item[x] = x;                  //input values into item array

for (int x = 25; x > 0; x--) {
    index = rand() % x;     //generate random numbers
    arraystore[x] = item[index];
    while (index < x - 1) {             
        item[index] = item[index + 1];
        index++;
        }
    }
}
```

I map the arraystore into the 2d array in main

```
int main(){
int ddarray[25][25];
for(int j=0;j<25)
    for(int i=0;i<25;i++){
        int array[25];
        permutation(array);
        ddarray[j][i]=array[i];
    }
}
```

Here are some of results

192,**9**,**7**,3,**11**,20,18,**9**,23,**11**,21,5,**11**,17,5,12,**11**,3,10,**9**,2,5,**7**,**7**,19,
192,**5**,0,14,23,22,**6**,2,**20**,24,13,12,**21**,24,**21**,6,11,**21**,1,**20**,**5**,8,**6**,12,15,
192,21,**6**,**14**,**14**,**11**,**11**,8,17,19,9,**24**,**22**,**6**,**24**,**11**,**2**,**22**,**6**,13,**2**,18,6,14,20,

Did I do any wrong in the permutation function or miss something?

Thank you for answering my question!

Comment: Since `arraystore` is a 25 element array, `arraystore[x]` is out of bounds when `x` is 25 and you never visit `arraystore[0]`. You probably meant `arraystore[x - 1]`.

Comment: You may be interested in [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random non repeating number array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878202/generating-random-non-repeating-number-array-in-c)

Comment: [Non-repeating random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5382037/995714), [Random array generation with no duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20734774/995714)

Answer (score 3):

There are several things that could/must be improved here.

- First off, I would recommend using [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) instead of rolling your own version.
- The main issue that makes your program illegal C++: If `x` is `25`, then you try to write to `arraystore[x]`, which is past the end of a 25 element array. You probably want to write to `arraystore[x-1]`.
- The main issue that gives you repeating output: You are randomizing a new array for every `i` in the inner loop and then only use the `i`th element (so you generate `25*25` arrays with 25 elements each). It can happen (in fact, it is exceedingly likely) that you repeat some elements this way. The correct `main` would look like this:

  ```
  int main() {
      int ddarray[25][25];
      for (int j=0; j<25; ++j)
      {
          int array[25];
          permutation(array);
          for (int i=0; i<25; i++) {
              ddarray[j][i] = array[i];
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  (Note that a `++j` was missing in your original code too...)
- Your implementation of `permutation` is pretty inefficient, because it has to move lots of elements for every single output element. The standard [Fischer Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) just swaps the elements at the current output and randomly chosen index.
- Finally, I would suggest using `std::array` (or `std::vector`) instead of plain arrays. The latter are very inconvenient/surprising to work with (and have no standard-support for different sizes at runtime).

Answer (score 2):

A simple implementation in C++11 based on `std::shuffle` could look like this:

```
int main() {
   std::random_device rd;
   std::mt19937 g(rd());

   std::array<std::array<int, 25>, 25> ddarray;

   for (auto& a : ddarray) {
      std::iota(a.begin(), a.end(), 1);
      std::shuffle(a.begin(), a.end(), g);
   }    
}
```

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/0abgD0Yqv9K1B1D9.