# Arrays and random value

Tags: java, random

I have a problem with random and arrays. I have a list empty list and I want to add 8 some random values, but I don't want to some values was the same. To get some random value I use this code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            round = random.nextInt(31);
            while (temp.get(round).equals(mix)) {
                round = random.nextInt(31);
            }
            mix.add(temp.get(round));
        }
```

temp is list with 32 objects and mix is my list where I want to add 8 random values. But when I random some values sometimes I get the same values. How I can get random values but without duplicates?

Comment: You could convert your array to a list and use the contains method of the arraylist to check if it present. If not, add it. Else, generate a new one and try again. The conversion to list can be done by Arrays.asList() (if you're using Java 6)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unique random numbers in O(1)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-random-numbers-in-o1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While others have described ways to implement a new solution, I think yours can be fixed by changing a single line:

```
while (temp.get(round).equals(mix))
```

I guess the condition is supposed to check whether the element of `temp` at position `round` is already in `mix`. This should do:

```
while (mix.contains(temp.get(round))
```

The problem with the first line is that `equals` is defined to compare an object to any other kind of object, and thus compares an element of `temp`, which is probably not a collection itself, to `mix`, which is. Thus, the condition is always false. `Collection.contains` is the method to use, and you need to use the one of `mix`. (As others have also pointed out, a `Set` is best suited to a case where `contains` is applied often, but for 8 cases, as you need, it does not matter much whether `mix` is a `List` instead).

[edit]: By the way: since the upper bound in `random.nextInt(int)` is excluded, you should only ever get the final element of 32-size `temp` in your `mix` if you use `nextInt(32)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a shuffle list which basically maintains a list of all possible values and removes one when it's returned to you. This is often known as the Fisher-Yates shuffle.

The removal of returned items from the list prevents the same number from being returned twice, and you can see further details, and a Java implementation, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116872/generate-random-numbers-in-array/8116947#8116947).

Answer (score 3):

Make a Collection of 32 objects, shuffle them, and take the first 8 of them.

```
List <Integer> list = new ArrayList <Integer> ();       
for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
{
    list.add (i);
}
Collections.shuffle (list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add your numbers to a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). Keep adding items until your set has the correct number of items.

```
while (set.size() < n)
{
    int item = random.nextInt(m);
    set.add(item);
}
```

Note that this will probably perform fine for most situations. It will however perform badly if both `n` is large and `m - n` is small.

Answer (score 1):

Use Set. Put your rundom values to set until its size is equal to your predefined number (e.g. 8):

```
Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
Set<Integer> randomSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
while(randomSet.size() < 8) {
    randomSet.add(random.nextInt(31));
}
// now random set contains 8 different random numbers.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        int randomCounter = 31;

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        round = random.nextInt(randomCounter);
        int roundInTemp = temp.get(round);
        mix.add(rountInTemp);
        temp.remove(roundInTemp);
        randomCounter--;
    }
```

Other way is to shuffle temp list(with algorith you find fine) and use `list.sublist(0, 8)`