# Implement an algorithm to shuffle an array of numbers

Tags: java

I wrote codes for the following question but they don't work. I get random numbers but the shuffle method don't shuffle them. Would you please help me?

```
for( each index i)

   choose a random index j where j>=i.
   swap the elements at index i and j.
```

My code is:

```
public static void shuffle(int[] a){
   for( int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++){
       int range = a.length; 
       int j = (int) (Math.random() * range);
       swap(a, i, j);      
  }
}

public static void swap(int[] array, int i, int j){

        if (i != j) {
            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem? Where is your swap method?

Comment: What happened to the `j>=i` requirement?

Comment: In any case, why shuffle when you can SHUFFLE: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116872/generate-random-numbers-in-array/8116947#8116947

Comment: I don't know what would be the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is java.util.Collections.shuffle which works with List. I suggest to copy-paste the algorithm from src and change it to work with int[]:

```
public static void shuffle(int[] a) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = a.length; i > 1; i--) {
        swap(a, i - 1, rnd.nextInt(i));
    }
}

private static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = tmp;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    shuffle(a);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

prints

```
[8, 7, 3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5, 9]
```

Comment: Where I can find java.util.Collections.shuffle ? I can't see it in java API.

Comment: @user1995200 look for `Collections` class and `shuffle` is a static method in it

Comment: I can see that but there is no code here, it just explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your array to Integer Wrapper class and call the Collections.shuffle by converting Integer array to List. The snippet is below

you should have access to the Apache lang library, then you can use the ArrayUtils.toObject(int[]) method like this:

```
int [] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
Integer[] newArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(array);
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(newArray));
for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(newArray[i]);
}
```

If you donot have the Apcahe Lang Library, then you can do this way

```
Integer[] newArray = new Integer[array.length];
int i = 0;
for (int value : array) {
    newArray[i++] = Integer.valueOf(value);
}
```