# php random number within range - no repeat

Tags: php, random, numbers

Haven't been able to find what I'm looking for so far, so I'm asking for help.

I have a div with a class that needs to end in a number between 1 and 8, and I need it to be a random number, without repeating...

```
<div class="parallax parallax_<?php echo $random_number ?>"></div>
```

I figured this should be pretty simple, but I'm having trouble.

Currently, I have:

```
<div class="parallax parallax_<?php echo rand(1, 8); ?>"></div>
```

which works, but produces duplicates.

**EDIT**

So after testing, I realized I am running into a problem.  I am using this within a wordpress template.  I am querying a set of 6 posts, and for each set of posts, I am including the above parallax div.  So, I get a random, none repeating number for each query, but each query resets the numbers - giving me duplicates... Here is my entire code.

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'orderby'          => 'menu_order',
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'order'            => 'ASC'
  );
  $posts = get_posts( $args );
?>

<?php foreach (array_chunk($posts, 6, true) as $posts) :  ?>
  <div class="parallax parallax_<?php echo rand(1, 8); ?>"></div>
  <div class="posts_container">  
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

      <div class="post">
        <div class="post__thumbnail"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div>
        <div class="post__title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
      </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?> 
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: ___random number, without repeating___ is not strictly a randon number

Comment: How many of these do you put on the one page

Comment: @RiggsFolly multiple.  depends on a post count.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random numbers without repeats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778723/generating-random-numbers-without-repeats)

Comment: I think that EDIT is a big enough change to the question to warant you asking it as a new question

Answer (score 5):

I would do a `range` and `shuffle`:

```
$myRange = range(1, 8);
shuffle($myRange);
return $myRange[0];
```

Comment: Would be better to make the array static and pop one value off of it at a time. But using shuffle() is elegant and terse.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Didn't expect this from you. Just loop `$myRange`, which is what I intended.

Comment: I did say that I may have misunderstood how to run in 8 times correctly

Comment: Wow, @RiggsFolly Were you able to understand what Thamaraiselvam spoke? That was a bullet reply to what he said in Tamil.

Comment: Enaku enamo avan loop keyword a vachi catch panitan nu ninaikuren

Comment: @PraveenKumar Google translate does not make that good a job of it I am afraid, but I did guess Tamil

Comment: @RiggsFolly Google Translate is still a baby in terms of South Indian languages.

Comment: Ok, I did a less simplistic (some may say dumb) test and I retract my ignorant earlier comment

Comment: @RiggsFolly Mate, you are always awesome. No doubt. `:D` Was just kidding.

Comment: @PraveenKumar No I apologise. Its fine being a smart ass when you are right, but I was Soooo wrong it is almost painful.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Na... Don't worry. :D Shit happens.

Answer (score 4):

This code prevent duplicate and fits to any other test case scenario. Shuffling is not necessary, random element is based on `array_rand()` function.

To pick repetitively new random key it is necessary to use code in the loop.

```
// Array declaration
$a=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);

// Loop
$randomKey=array_rand($a);
unset($a[$randomKey]);

// Test
echo $randomKey."<br>";
var_dump($a);
```

First it is defined an array of numbers which are desired. Than random key from array is picked. It is also unset from array so it will be not used again.

For repeating action `$randomKey` and `unset()` should be in loop. Echo and `var_dump()` function is only for testing purpose. Array size can decrease unsetting already used key or stay same length leaving `unset()` function from the loop.

Comment: This looks good but should `echo $a[$randomKey];` and move the `unset` to after you echo the number!!!!!

Comment: Order doesn't matter. You can do as you please, test part is only for informative purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `uniqid()` function along with `md5` to strengthen the results:

```
 md5(uniqid(rand(1, 8), true));
```

Or use [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.shuffle.php).

```
$numbers = range(1, 8);
shuffle($numbers);

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo "$number ";
}
```

Comment: Does not prevent duplicates.

Comment: And uniqid() and md5() do not make the result more random.

Comment: Maybe, but it's a start. Also in the loop he can add a counter to the end of each number to make it even more unique. Please do post a better answer. I dare you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you. 
`shuffle()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

```
<?php
$numbers = range(1, 8);
shuffle($numbers);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo "$number ";
}
```