# Algorithm to generate array of all possible 5 digit combinations of numbers in range 2-9, no repeating digits

Tags: php

I am looking for an algorithm to generate an array of all possible 5 digit combinations of numbers in range 2-9 while having no repeating digits in combinations.
For example:
23456
37895
62784
96742
83467
...

What i don't want to see is for example:
22456
34463
44444
78772
...

I have got code, which generates all possible combinations, but having repeating numbers in combinations. So maybe that array could be filtered instead having only combinations which contain unique digits.

```
function sampling($chars, $size, $combinations = array()) {
    $charsArray = str_split($chars);
    # if it's the first iteration, the first set 
    # of combinations is the same as the set of characters
    if (empty($combinations)) {
        $combinations = $charsArray;
    }

    # we're done if we're at size 1
    if ($size == 1) {
        return $combinations;
    }

    # initialise array to put new values in
    $new_combinations = array();

    # loop through existing combinations and character set to create strings
    foreach ($combinations as $combination) {
        foreach ($charsArray as $char) {
            $new_combinations[] = $combination . $char;
        }
    }
    # call same function again for the next iteration
    return sampling($chars, $size - 1, $new_combinations);

}

// example

$output = sampling("23456789", 5);
print "<pre>";print_r($output);
```

Comment: `var_dump(count($output) === count(array_unique($output)));` gives me true.

Comment: I don't really get what numbers you're trying to generate. You say "in range 2-9" but show an example with "12345" (starting with a "1") which is not in that range?

Comment: see if this helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778723/generating-random-numbers-without-repeats#:~:text=php%20function%20randomGen(%24min%2C,generates%2020%20unique%20random%20numbers%20%3F%3E

Comment: What i need is all possible combinations which only consist of unique digits or perhaps the array created by the code, which i provided, can be filtered. I have also edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$var = [];
for ($i = 20000; $i <= 99999; $i++) {
    $pass = true;
    if(is_numeric(strpos((string) $i, "0")) || is_numeric(strpos((string) $i, "1"))) {
        $pass = false;
    }
    if($pass) {
        $var[] = $i;
    }
}

foreach($var as $v) {
    echo "$v \n";
}
```

`php script.php | grep 0`

`php script.php | grep 1`

If you have repeating numbers you can use `array_unique`

But with the code above, you are sure not to omit or repeat anything