# Array adds dimension when randomized

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, slice

Allo'

I'm working on a little project of mine and part of it involves taking a two dimensional array already created and randomizing it.

So I have something which looks like this:

```
foo = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]];

randomizeFoo = function(){ 
    var randomizedFoo = [];
    newFoo = foo;
    for(i = 0; i < newFoo.length; i++){
        count = Math.random() * newFoo.length;
        randomizedFoo.push(newFoo.slice(count, count + 1));
    }
    return randomizedFoo; 
};
```

This does indeed randomize the array but I end up with something like this:

```
randomizedFoo = [[[7,8]],[[1,2]],[[5,6]],[[3,4]]]
```

My nice neat 2D array is now a 3D array with the lowest level arrays now burred under an extra level.  I realize that this is not really that big a deal and the rest of my code just needs to compensate but it bugs me for 2 reasons:

1. It's extra complexity and that's never good.
2. I don't like my code doing things without me knowing the reason why.

Anybody have any ideas as to why it's doing this?  I put a 2D array in, I want a 2D array back out again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/362536

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using slice. Just use count as the index into foo. As in : randomizedFoo.push(foo[count]);

Make sure you make count an int first.

Comment: This worked.  After the randomizedFoo.push(foo[count]); I added a foo.splice(count, 1); to remove the value I'd pushed to the new array, otherwise I would get duplicates in the new array.  Much obliged for the help, it would seem that I have more to learn about the splice method.

Comment: No worries. There's always more to learn, probably! It seems that splice returns anything it finds inside an array, so your values, even if only a single entry long, will get wrapped in another array.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the script from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208121/javascript-making-an-random-array/13208363#13208363) and use `map` with it:

```
foo = range(0, foo.length-1, true).map(function(i) {
  return foo[i];
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/ayepeh/1/edit (ctrl + enter to refresh)

Comment: This is a really cool script.  Thanks for pointing me in this direction, there's a lot I can learn from this.