# Generate random number within range without repeating numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate 8 unique random numbers between 1 and 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-8-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100)
>   [Generate unique number within range (0 - X), keeping a history to prevent duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808804/generate-unique-number-within-range-0-x-keeping-a-history-to-prevent-duplic)

I need loop that will run 80 times and generate random number between 0-79 but it will not repeat number that has been generated already.
How can I do that?

Comment: Put all numbers in an array. Shuffle. Take first. Remove first. Relevant questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-a-javascript-array, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-8-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100

Comment: @FelixKling that doesn't solve the problem of generating uniques to populate the array with in the first place.

Comment: @Asad: Has been answered before though. And since they need 80 numbers and have exactly 80 numbers (0-79), there is no need to generate them. All that is left to do is to put 0-80 in an array and shuffle that array.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
  for (var i = 0, ar = []; i < 80; i++) {
    ar[i] = i;
  }

  // randomize the array
  ar.sort(function () {
      return Math.random() - 0.5;
  });
```

// You have array ar with numbers 0 to 79 randomized. Verify
`console.log(ar);`

// take out elements like this
`ar.pop()`

Comment: why ` - 0.5` ?  Just did a test and it didn't seem to make a difference. But I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: nevermind.  I found the explanation here:  https://teamtreehouse.com/community/return-mathrandom05