# How to select a few random id values from an array based on a matching argument?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have an array of 700 question objects that look like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: "5ca3216579a592b0910f70d4"
    question: "Who wrote Twilight series of novels?"
    answer: "Stephenie Meyer"
    category: "Art and Literature"
  },
  ...
]
```

I also have an array of 3 selected question categories that look like this:

```
["Art and Literature", "Music", "History"]
```

What I basically need is 4 random questions of each question category. 
So:

- 4 random questions of Art and Literature
- 4 random questions of Music
- 4 random questions of History

Ideally I think it would be nice to have the 12 random question id's set in a new array based on these 3 categories so I could send them to my database.

How is this to be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)

Comment: That's not what my question is about at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const questions = [
    {
      _id: "5ca3216579a592b0910f70d4",
      question: "Who wrote Twilight series of novels?",
      answer: "Stephenie Meyer",
      category: "Art and Literature",
    }
  ]

const categories = ["Art and Literature", "Music", "History"];

const numberOfEachCategory = 2;


const randSelected = categories.map((category) => {
    const filtered = questions.filter((obj) => obj.category === category).slice();

    if(filtered.length > numberOfEachCategory) {
        const randomArray = [];

        for(let i = numberOfEachCategory; i > 0; i--) {
            randomArray.push(...filtered.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * filtered.length), 1));
        }

        return randomArray;

    } else {
        return filtered;
    }
})

console.log(randSelected);
```

Result is Array of Arrays. each inside array for each category

Answer (score 2):

You should first create an array of questions for each category to randomly select from.

```
const art = arr.filter(question => question.category === 'Art and Literature');
const music = arr.filter(question => question.category === 'Music');
const history = arr.filter(question => question.category === 'History');
```

Now, just choose items randomly four times for each category array.

```
const categoryArrays = [art, music, history];

const results = [] // to store the selected ids 

for (i = 0, i < 3, i++) { // To iterate over the three categories 
  for (j = 0, j < 4, j++) { // To select four times 
    results.push(categoryArrays[i][Math.floor(Math.random() * categoryArrays[i].length)]._id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of steps to this. First you'll want to filter out a list of items for the specific category.

```
const categories = ["Art and Literature", "Music", "History"];

for (let c of categories) {
    const itemsOfCategory = items.filter(i => item.category === c);
}
```

Then you'll want to pick 4 random items from the filtered list and return them. It seems nicest to put this in it's own function.

```
const getRandomItems = (items, categories, numberOfItems) => {
    const results = [];
    for (let c of categories) {
        const itemsOfCategory = items.filter(i => i.category === c);
        const pickedItems = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i += 1) {
      pickedItems.push(Math.trunc(Math.random()*itemsOfCategory.length))
        }
    results.push(pickedItems)
    }
  return results;
}
```

You then pass in your list of items, the categories you want and how many items you want.

`const randomItems = getRandomItems(items, categories, 4);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` on `categories` array and then inside the callback use `filter` to get an array of objects where category matches. On first iteration it will give an array where the category is `Art and Literature` and so on. Then run another loop to get generate 4 random numbers and using this random number get a random question from filtered array.Store that value in a temporary variable and return that

```
let ques = [{
  _id: "5ca3216579a592b0910f70d4"
  question: "Who wrote Twilight series of novels?"
  answer: "Stephenie Meyer"
  category: "Art and Literature"
}]


let type = ["Art and Literature", "Music", "History"];

let randomQues = type.map(function(item) {
  let quesArrays = []
  let k = ques.filter(elem) {
    return elem.category === item;
  }) for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * k.length);
  quesArrays.push(rand)
}
return quesArrays;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could group all question ids by categories using reduce(), and then pick N random items from these arrays:

```js
const categories = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'];
const questions = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => (
  { _id: i, question: `question ${i}`, answer: `answer ${i}`, category: categories[Math.floor(Math.random() * categories.length)]})
);
  
function randomQuestions(questions, categories, n) {
  // group the ids into arrays for each category asked
  const idsByCategories = questions.reduce((acc, x) => {
    if (categories.includes(x.category)) {
      acc[x.category] = [...(acc[x.category] || []), x._id];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
  // pick a number of random ids for each category
  return categories.map(cat => (idsByCategories[cat] || []).sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()).slice(0, n));
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(randomQuestions(questions, ['cat1', 'cat3'], 2)));

console.log(questions);
```

The random array picking code was taken [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38571132/9325419).

Answer (score 0):

Use shuffle function to remdomize the array containing questions than just take first top 4 results by matching category.

Here is pseudo code:

```
let arrayOfQuestions =[];
let shuffledQuestions = _.shuffle(arrayOfQuestions); // _ is Lodash
let artAndLiteratureQuestions = _.find(shuffledQuestions, { category: 'Art and Literature' }
```

in the same way you can extract the others category questions.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this logic to **get all results** in one liner for **all categories** :) Just need to change filter check with your check.

```js
let list = [1,1,1,1, 1, 1,1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];
let options = [1, 3];

const result = options.map((val) => {
  return list.filter(f => val === f ).map((v, i, ref) => {
    if(i<=3)
      return ref[parseInt(Math.random()*ref.length-i)]
}).slice(0, 3)
})

console.log(result);
```