# Angular pick a random item from an array within a service

Tags: arrays, angular

Ok, let me start by saying that Angular is relatively new to me. However with the help of the Angular Hero tutorials I did manage to create a website which can do the following:

Show cooking recipes. The recipes are feed from a Recipe service. When clicked on a recipe, it shows the details of that particular recipe. It is all based on this tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

But I am missing one functionality: showing three random recipes on the homepage.
I assume that I don't have to loop through all recipes again. I would rather make 3 random numbers (randomNumber1 etc..) and then display them like this:

```
<div class="dish-block">
  <a routerLink="/detail/{{ recipe[randomNumber1].id }}">
    <img src="assets/img/{{ recipe[randomNumber1].image }}"/>
    <div class="dish-block-caption">
      <p>{{ recipe[randomNumber1].name }}</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

However, this does not seem to work. It gives me: TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

So the question remains: How can I display a random item from an array in a service?

**mock-recipes.ts**

```
import { Recipe } from './recipe';

export const RECIPES: Recipe[] = [
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Dish 1',
        time: '10min',
        image: 'dish.jpg',
        persons: 2,
        steps: [
            'eerste stap',
            'tweede stap',
            'derde stap'
        ],
        ingredients: [
            'vier',
            'vijf',
            'zes'
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Dish 2',
        time: '20min',
        image: 'dish.jpg',
        persons: 2,
        steps: [
            'eerste stap',
            'tweede stap',
            'derde stap'
        ],
        ingredients: [
            'vier',
            'vijf',
            'zes'
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Dish 3',
        time: '30min',
        image: 'dish.jpg',
        persons: 2,

        steps: [
            'eerste stap',
            'tweede stap',
            'derde stap'
        ],
        ingredients: [
            'vier',
            'vijf',
            'zes'
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Dish 4',
        time: '40min',
        image: 'dish.jpg',
        persons: 2,
        steps: [
            'eerste stap',
            'tweede stap',
            'derde stap'
        ],
        ingredients: [
            'vier',
            'vijf',
            'zes'
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Dish 5',
        time: '50min',
        image: 'dish.jpg',
        persons: 2,
        steps: [
            'eerste stap',
            'tweede stap',
            'derde stap'
        ],
        ingredients: [
            'vier',
            'vijf',
            'zes'
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Dish 6',
        time: '60min',
        image: 'dish.jpg',
        persons: 2,
        steps: [
            'eerste stap',
            'tweede stap',
            'derde stap'
        ],
        ingredients: [
            'vier',
            'vijf',
            'zes'
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        name: 'Dish 7',
        time: '70min',
        image: 'dish.jpg',
        persons: 2,
        steps: [
            'eerste stap',
            'tweede stap',
            'derde stap'
        ],
        ingredients: [
            'vier',
            'vijf',
            'zes'
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        name: 'Dish 8',
        time: '80min',
        image: 'dish.jpg',
        persons: 2,
        steps: [
            'eerste stap',
            'tweede stap',
            'derde stap'
        ],
        ingredients: [
            'vier',
            'vijf',
            'zes'
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        name: 'Dish 9',
        time: '90min',
        image: 'dish.jpg',
        persons: 2,
        steps: [
            'eerste stap',
            'tweede stap',
            'derde stap'
        ],
        ingredients: [
            'vier',
            'vijf',
            'zes'
        ]
    }
];
```

**recipe.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Recipe } from './recipe';
import { RECIPES } from './mock-recipes';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class RecipeService {

    constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

    getRecipes(): Observable<Recipe[]> {
        this.messageService.add('RecipeService: fetched recipes');
        return of(RECIPES);
    }

    getRecipe(id: number): Observable<Recipe> {
        this.messageService.add(`RecipeService: fetched recipe id=${id}`);
        return of(RECIPES.find(recipe => recipe.id === id));
    }
}
```

**suggestion.component.ts**
(this is the ts file of the html that should display 3 random recipes)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from '../recipe';
import { RecipeService } from '../recipe.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-suggestion',
    templateUrl: './suggestion.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./suggestion.component.scss']
})
export class SuggestionComponent implements OnInit {
    recipes: Recipe[];
    randomNumber: number;

    constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getRecipes();
        this.randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
    }

    getRecipes(): void {
        this.recipeService.getRecipes()
        .subscribe(recipes => this.recipes = recipes);
    }
}
```

I am really stuck at this moment and would love to receive some advice.
Thanks in advance!

**Update**
I have managed to create a JS function which generates an array with 3 random values. However, I can't find a way to connect my recipe.service to that JS file. Should I change something in the suggestion.component.ts in order to let it communicate with the mock.recipes?

**Update2**
It now works with the help of the community, thanks!

My TS file now looks like this:

**suggestion.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from '../recipe';
import { RecipeService } from '../recipe.service';

declare function getRandom(): any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-suggestion',
    templateUrl: './suggestion.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./suggestion.component.scss']
})
export class SuggestionComponent implements OnInit {
    recipes: Recipe[];
    threeRandomRecipes: any;
    randomId: number;

    constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getRecipes();
        this.getThreeRandomRecipes();
    }

    getThreeRandomIds() {
        const randomIds = [];
        while (1) {
            this.randomId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            if (randomIds.includes(this.randomId)) {
                continue;
            } else {
                randomIds.push(this.randomId);
                if (randomIds.length === 3) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return randomIds;
    }

    getRecipes(): void {
        this.recipeService.getRecipes()
        .subscribe(recipes => this.recipes = recipes);
    }

    getRecipe(id) {
        return this.recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.id === id)[0];
    }

    getThreeRandomRecipes() {
        const randomIds = this.getThreeRandomIds();
        this.threeRandomRecipes = randomIds.map(id => this.getRecipe(id));
    }
}
```

After that I had to add some interpolation like this:

```
<div class="dish">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4" *ngFor="let suggestion of threeRandomRecipes">
                    <div class="dish-block">
                        <a routerLink="/detail/{{ suggestion.id }}">
                            <img src="assets/img/{{ suggestion.image }}"/>
                            <div class="dish-block-timer">
                                <p>{{ suggestion.time }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dish-block-caption">
                                <p>{{ suggestion.name }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you can get 3 random numbers(ids) and push the recipes with those ids into an array(which can be a property of the class) and in your HTML use `*ngFor` directive to loop through the recipes.

You can try something like this in your component.ts:

```
threeRandomRecipes: any;

getThreeRandomIds() {
  const randomIds = [];
  while(1) {
    randomId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    if (randomIds.includes(randomId)) {
      continue;
    } else {
      randomIds.push(randomId);
      if (randomIds.length === 3) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return randomIds;
}


getRecipe(id) {
  return this.recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.id === id)[0];
}

getThreeRandomRecipes() {
  const randomIds =this.getThreeRandomIds();
  this.threeRandomRecipes = randomIds.map(id => this.getRecipe(id));
}
```

So you can call the last function after you have all the recipes and then use the threeRandomRecipes property in your template by using ngFor and string interpolation.

Comment: So you mean to create a new array with 3 random ID's? And then loop through that new array?

Comment: create an array of 3 recipes based on 3 random ids and you can use string interpolation to display the content.

Comment: This is the point were I am stuck: "push the recipes with those ids into an array"

Comment: @Dennis updated my answer with some simple functions to get an array with three random recipes. You can improve them as you like.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh! That is very kind of you, since I haven't found a solution yet I will give this a try for sure

Answer (score 0):

I believe your difficulty is getting randomly 3 elements out of k (> 3) in that case what you need is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269545/how-to-get-n-no-elements-randomly-from-an-array)

After you have that array you can proceed the way Ramesh explained

Comment: Thank you ParrapbanzZ! I will take a look