# Getting multiple random strings from array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

how can I get multiple **random** strings from array of strings.
For example:

```
const arr = [
'Text1',
'Text2',
'Text3',
'Text4',
'Text5'
]
```

And result:

```
const randomStrings = [
'Text1',
'Text4'
]
```

Comment: is the resulting number of  elements a constant ? like only 2 elements everytime ? or that can be random too ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269545/how-to-get-n-no-elements-randomly-from-an-array and this too

Comment: It doesnt answer the question because that examples are for returning one value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Math.random()`. This will generate a random number between 0 and 1 (excluding 1). You can then multiply this number by the length of the array, and use `Math.floor()` to generate an index in the array. When we use `splice`, it will mutate the original array, but it ensures that there will not be duplicate values.

```js
const arr = ['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3', 'Text4', 'Text5']
const out = []
const elements = 2

for (let i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
  out.push(...arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length), 1))
}

console.log(out)
```

As mentioned by Terry, it would be better to create a local copy of the array so that it is not modified. It also allows to pass parameters to choose the number of elements returned:

```js
const arr = ['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3', 'Text4', 'Text5']

const getRandomElements = (a, n) => {
  const l = a.slice()
  const o = []
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    o.push(...l.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * l.length), 1))
  }
  return o
}

console.log(getRandomElements(arr, 2))
console.log(getRandomElements(arr, 3))
console.log(getRandomElements(arr, 4))
```

Comment: Just a note: this will cause `arr` to be modified. It might make more sense to abstract all that logic into a function, so that you can pass an array into the function and the function makes a local copy of the array before splicing it :)

Comment: @Terry I addressed that in my answer, I'll add a solution that doesn't modify it now :)

Comment: No problem. I like your approach! :) It's beautiful.

Comment: @ShinyDiamond No worries. If you need more help, feel free to ask 