# Function to pick N random items from array in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

This is the code. Got the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38571132/10128619).

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7zASwQawEoCGyAJhALYCSMwZqcAvHADwAqco1JdArsjshADuyANoBdAHxwAFAShQAXHBYAaOMiXJuZAEbAoASiVt6UgN4AoOIhTo4qABbcAZs4A2wYgzgBBeQQBPADpnKHJZeQMg1GgYaWkDBikABiCAVjgAWjgAWQIYByCoIlIyBIMAbis4KGAYbihkeydXD2Jot2xgaWS1ZEqLAF8qiwtQSFgbNAxsfBLyKhpUADUAJm9WdhBOYh4+AWFxKQjFZT7NbT1DYyS4S2skaeaXd09vP2Lg0PC5Q2jY+KJUxwVIZbJ5ApFeZlAwDay1eqNZ6tTwdLo9PqJAh0FhVYYWIA)

I'm using the generic type parameter: `T extends unknown[]`, since this function should work for any kind of array.

```
export const pickRandomItems = <T extends unknown[]> (arr: T, n: number): T => {
  const shuffled = Array.from(arr).sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
  return shuffled.slice(0, n);
};
```

But I'm getting the following error on the `return` statement:

[image]

[image]

It goes away if I do a type assertion. But why is that necessary? Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

**NOTE:**

The following line is evaluated as `unknown[]`, so why is the type assertion necessary anyway?

```
const result = shuffled.slice(0, n);
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. "_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the type parameter to be the array item, not the whole array:

```
export const pickRandomItems = <T extends unknown> (arr: T[], n: number): T[] => {
  const shuffled = Array.from(arr).sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
  return shuffled.slice(0, n);
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7zASwQawEoCGyAJhALYCSMwZqcAvHADwAqco1JdArsjshADuyAHxwAFAShQAXHBYBtALoAaOMjnJuZAEbAoASjmKlDMQG8AUHEQp0cVAAtuAMxcAbYMQZwAgtIIATwA6FyhySWkDYNRoGHFxAzM4AAZggFY4AFo4AFkCGEdgqCJSMkSDAG5rOChgGG4oZAdnN09iGPdsYHEUtWQqywBfSqA)

While `T extends unknown[]` does mean `T` can be any array, it could also be a subtype of `Array`,  which means `slice` will not return the appropriate type (it will return `Array` instead of whatever `T` is). Generally you can't assign a concrete type to a generic type parameter, because the generic type parameter could be any sub type that is decided by the caller, while you are using a specific concrete type in your implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you're having is that T can be any subtype of `unknown[]`, however your function returns an array. Thus, typescript warns you that an array cannot be cast to `T`, which could be some subclass of an array. Instead, you can change T to be the item, and take an iterable as an argument and return an array:

```
// trailing comma in generic so ts doesn't confuse with jsx
export const pickRandomItems = <T,> (arr: Iterable<T>, n: number): T[] => {
  const shuffled = Array.from(arr).sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
  return shuffled.slice(0, n);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I've never used the `Iterable` interface. Do you have any documentation on it?

Comment: [Here's a more detailed page from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol) and [here's a more tutorial-like page from javascript.info](https://javascript.info/iterable). Basically, an iterable is anything that implements a `Symbol.iterator` function that returns an iterator, allowing `Array.from` to collect the iterator into an array.