# How to get random data from API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to get random id from data obtained through an api in vuejs. Then i'm trying create a code like this.

```
data() {
   return {
     mostPlayed: [],
     randomData: [],
   }
},
created() {
   this.randomData = this.randomItem(this.mostPlayed);
},
methods: {
   async getMostPlayed() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        const data = response.data.slice(0, 9);
        this.mostPlayed = data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      },
   randomItem (items) {
      return items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
    }
},
mounted() {
   this.getMostPlayed();
}
```

Sample data

```
[ 
 {
   id: 1
   title: "Forza Horizon 5"
 },
 {
   id: 2
   title: "Apex Legends"
 },
 {
   id: 3
   title: "Battlefield 2042"
 },
 {
   id: 4
   title: "Fortnite"
 },
 {
   id: 5
   title: "Genshin Impact"
 },
]
```

But nothing happened. I want to get random id with sample data like that. Example output like this. [ { id: 3 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 5 } ].

Comment: use console.log and check receiving data is correct ?

Comment: The data is probably not yet loaded when the `created` lifecycle is called.

Comment: @sajjad result console.log is undefined

Comment: @Kokodoko hmm ok, so what should i do?

Comment: @BlekWit Please check for the answer I posted. That would solve the problem. Let me know if you still face any issue

Comment: @BlekWit the answer shows how to fill the `mostplayed` variable once `axios` has returned the api data.

Comment: @Vipulw already sir, but i got a new error

Comment: @Kokodoko can you give a example code sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling method for API call in mounted and generating the random list from the most played list in created. But as per the lifecycle diagram of vue given [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#lifecycle-diagram), you can see that created hook comes first and then mounted hook. So that way you are creating random list on an empty most played array.

As a solution call the `getMostPlayed` method inside created and `randomItem`  method inside `getMostPlayed` after API response.

Something like this :

```
data() {
    return {
        mostPlayed: [],
        randomData: [],
    }
},
created() {
    this.getMostPlayed();
},
methods: {
    async getMostPlayed() {
         try {
             const response = await axios.get(url);
             const data = response.data.slice(0, 9);
             this.mostPlayed = data;
             this.randomData = this.randomItem(this.mostPlayed);
         } catch (error) {
             console.log(error);
         },
    randomItem (items) {
         return items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
     }
}
```

Please refer to answers to this question if you want to have multiple random elements as current logic is to get a single random element from an array : [Get multiple random elements from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269545/how-to-get-a-number-of-random-elements-from-an-array)

Comment: ok, i try this code and then got a new message. there is said "[vue-router] missing param for named route "GameDetail": Expected "id" to be defined". But i try to console.log(this.randomData), only one data appears.

Comment: The logic written in randomItem method would always return single element is what I think. The Consider checking that logic here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array

Comment: hmm ok, but is it possible to return a lot of random data in the form of an array?

Comment: @BlekWit I have updated my answer with link to similar question. I think what you are asking is a completely different question overall, and I would like you to take look at existing answers rather than we discussing here. If my answer helped you, please upvote and accept to help other people facing similar issue. Cheers & Thanks : )

Comment: ok sir, actually i was just asking. but thank you so much for your answer