# How to generate an array with not repeating numbers in ES6?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate an array of random numbers in ES6 - numbers should not be repeated.

Currently, my function generates an array of random numbers, but they are repeating:

```
winArray = [...Array(6)].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 53));
```

Here is non-ES6 solution that I've found:
[Non-ES6 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806210/generating-non-repeating-random-numbers-in-js)

This solution with Set is not running in a for-loop:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= draws; i += 1) {
      // Generating a random array of 6 number

      const winArray = new Set();
      while (winArray.size < 6) winArray.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * 53));
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with a nonES6 solution?

Comment: You mean like [Generate unique number within range (0 - X), keeping a history to prevent duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11808804/1048572)?

Comment: No, I need an array of 6 numbers

Comment: but the solution you have is interesting too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and fill this set until the wanted size.

```js
var numbers = new Set;

while (numbers.size < 6) numbers.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * 53));

console.log(...numbers);
```

For getting more numbser sets, you could take an empty set for each draw.

```js
var numbers,
    draws = 5,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < draws; i++) {
    numbers = new Set;
    while (numbers.size < 6) numbers.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * 53));

    console.log(...numbers);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this code in the for loop, but it looks like this approach is not working in for loop

Comment: a for loop needs only the comparison part. please see edit.

Comment: I mean the for loop outside an array generation :)
please, take a look at the edited post

Comment: i dont understand what you like to get. btw, `winArray` is a set, not an array. why do you have a for loop. what is it for?

Comment: I'm creating a lottery app. For-loop iterates through each drop and create a unique array of numbers for each draws. Does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 3):

A [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) will only allow unique properties (no duplicates).

```js
let winArray = [...Array(6)].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 53));

winArray = [...new Set(winArray)]

console.log(winArray)
```

Comment: Hind sight is 20/20, Nina smashed it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that shuffles a list of unique numbers (no repeats, ever).

```
for (var a=[],i=0;i<100;++i) a[i]=i;

function shuffle(array) {
  var tmp, current, top = array.length;
  if(top) while(--top) {
    current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (top + 1));
    tmp = array[current];
    array[current] = array[top];
    array[top] = tmp;
  }
  return array;
}

a = shuffle(a);
```