# Generate different random numbers within a range

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, random

I want to generate n different numbers between 1 and N (of course n<=N). N could be very large.
If n is very small, one efficient way is generating a numbers and compare it with the set we have got to make sure it's a new number. It takes O(n^2) time and O(n) memory.
If n is quite large, we can use Fisher–Yates shuffle algorithm to generate a random permutation( stop after n steps). It takes O(n) time, but we also must use O(N) memory.

Here is the question. What can we do if we do not know how large n is?
I hope that the algorithm just use O(n) memory and stop after O(n) time. Is that possible?

Comment: That's a pretty poor duplicate - N there is 1000, here could be "very large".

Comment: @j_random_hacker That uses O(N) memory (not O(n)).

Comment: @jrok: Fair enough, close vote retracted.  I do note however an O(1)-space solution on that page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/202225/47984.

Comment: Jerry Coffin's dupe is a much better fit for this -- it's completely unbiased, and if a tree structure is used to hold the numbers chosen then it's O(n)-space and O(log n) time to select each element.  I doubt any data structure can improve this to O(1) time to select each element.

Comment: How can you not know how large `n` is, yet perform the calculation? What is wrong with an algorithm that says "oh look, n is 5. I will do this..."

Comment: @Floris: The way I interpret it is that they want an *online* algorithm -- i.e. one where it's always possible to cheaply add a new, distinct sample later on.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: If you implement the set as a hash table you can get O(1) (at least for the expected time).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: You're right, I was getting my n and N confused...  but somehow only w.r.t. the hashtable, not the tree!

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Happens to the best of us (well, I guess I don't know about the best, but I've seen it happen to a lot better than me, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can essentially do the same as for very small *n*, but just make that check more efficient. For example the naïve method of checking if you've already generated a number is to just linearly search the list of previously generated values. For an unknown *n* you could keep the set of previously generated values sorted so that you can use a more efficient search for identifying duplicates. With the naïve approach the algorithm takes O(n<sup>2</sup>) time, but a smarter search through previous results can reduce that to O(n*log<sub>2</sub> n).

Comment: Inserting a value into a sorted array is O(n) time though.  And if n is a large enough fraction of N that duplicates turn up often then an exponential term appears in the time complexity to account for the time spent rerunning it, and will dominate it.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: The array doesn't need to be sorted. It could just as easily be a hash table.

Comment: @j_random_hacker so don't use an array. A tree can have O(log n) searching and insertion and is easy to keep sorted.

Comment: @bames53: I would suggest changing your answer to say that, but I don't think it addresses the main problem I identified -- the exponential time complexity that results when already-selected numbers become sufficiently dense.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: You can exponentially rehash a hash table resulting in amortized linear insertion cost, just like a vector. Random numbers are *ideal* as hash-table keys, too.

Comment: @rici: Sorry, got my n and N confused...  Serious caffeine shortage here.  Comment deleted.