# Generate Random & Unique Number and Insert into Database

Tags: java, random, unique, sql-insert

My goal is to generate random number and insert into database. I do not want any duplication. I have done my research, one of is to check at database first, and then insert.

```
//GENEREATE RANDOM NUMBER
long number = (long) Math.floor(Math.random() * 900000L) + 900000L;


//CHECK IF NUMBER IS ALREADY EXIST IN DATABASE
String searchQuery = "select appleId from food where appleId='" + number + "'";
         try {
             Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(searchQuery);
             boolean appleIdExists = rs.next();

//IT IS UNIQUE  

if (!appleIdExists) {

            try {
                //INSERT STATEMENT
                       .......
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                }

//IT IS NOT UNIQUE..
                else
                {
                       .....

                }

                }catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out
                    .println("Log In failed: An Exception has occurred! "
                            + ex);
        }
```

So my **problem** is if it NOT unique, I need to generate another number and check again? And check again and again until it is unique? Will the result be many if-else statement?

I am not sure if use if-else statement is the efficient way. Or there is another way?

Any suggestion?

Help will be appreciate! :)

Comment: Use a loop instead of if/else.

Comment: Is this the only thing inserting into the table? If not, this won't be good enough anyway as between your check and your insert the number could be inserted. Instead, add a constraint onto the table, *try* to perform an insert, and catch whatever constraint violation exception is thrown and try again. Additionally, you should use parameterized SQL rather than string concatenation. Also look into using whatever facilities the database itself provides for this - if you *really* just want a unique ID, there are lots of ways of going about that. How important is randomness?

Comment: Does it have to be a number?  Could it be a GUID instead?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Comment: @JonSkeet It is not the only thing.. there are more, but I never include here.

Comment: @Taylor It is 5 digit number.

Comment: @newbieinjava: How certain are you that you'll never need more than 100,000 entries? Note that later on (when the table is nearly "full") it's going to get really expensive to keep querying until you happen to find a good one...

Comment: @newbieinjava Ok.  You'll get 6-7 digits from your code.  What I'm asking is does it need to be a number?  Can it instead be a GUID (aka UUID)? (I don't know your requirements, but if you can use a GUID this becomes much easier, as you can assume uniqueness).

Comment: Why not use a "sequence"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use an auto incrementing identity column in the database, essentially making the database create a unique id for you?  Every modern DBMS supports this capability.

For [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html):

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

For PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE animals
(
    id             serial primary key,
    name        VARCHAR(40) not null
);
```

All databases have this capability, and when you use JDBC to insert a row, you get back the key of the inserted row in the response.  A simplified example:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES ('zebra')";
Integer insertedId = stmt.executeUpdate(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Comment: The issue is, sometimes you want this random number not to be predictable. Using auto increment, it's very predictable to know which numbers are already assigned.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is generate random numbers and insert into database, then you can use [Fisher Yates shuffle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Check this question for details: [Unique (non-repeating) random numbers in O(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-random-numbers-in-o1)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can hold the random numbers (generated/existing) to a collection/or cache or queue. don't need to check every time in DB.
   Try to do the operations in batch. either first generate all the unique random numbers and the persist based on your requirement.
2. Define an Unique ID on the column - don't need to do a select and insert, just do a INSERT in case of failure repeat the same process.
3. You can use recursion as we don't know the failure's count.

theexamtime.com